# "Votes" label isn't centered on locked posts with an extreme score

Tags: bug, design, locked-questions

The "votes" label underneath a locked post with an extreme score is not centered:

[image]

It's set to `text-align: left`; it needs to be set to `center`.

Comment: I had a post about something similar that was set to [tag:status-completed], and mentioned it there, but a month and a half later, it is still not fixed.