# We are graduating the updated button styling for vote arrows

Tags: discussion, design, voting, announcements

### Update

This experiment has been graduated. The new styling for vote arrows is now live across the Stack Exchange network.

---

About a year ago, the Product team, focused on improving the general experience, conducted an experiment to [update the styling of the voting arrows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded) on Stack Overflow in order to improve accessibility and meet [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/) compliance. We shared positive results from the experiment: **a net 28% increase in overall votes**.

At the time, we decided to not move forward for a few reasons:

1. We wanted to take a broader approach to looking at the question page instead of one particular element and decided to roll this into a different initiative.
2. Additional accessibility issues were raised that needed to be re-tested in dark/high contrast modes

We’ve decided to revisit our decision and to graduate the experiment on Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network. Before we proceed, we acknowledge there are still a few outstanding accessibility issues and bugs that we need to address first before we graduate.

Here is what the arrows look like before and after the change:

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Screenshot of the voting buttons before the change (simple up and down arrows)] | [image: Screenshot of voting buttons after the change (arrows with circles around them] |

### Your feedback

We’ve heard your feedback from the previous posts about this change, and are not moving forward until we address them. We are prioritizing issues specific to accessibility compliance and bug reports. This might mean that any drastic visual changes to the styling will not be within the scope of this first iteration, but that does not mean we won’t iterate the design.

Moving forward, we are committed to:

1. Prioritization of bug and accessibility reports to be addressed *before* we go live such as:

   - [Visibility of non-checked button in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded/418857#418857)
   - [Contrast ratio issues in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded/418888#418888)
   - [Visibility of highlight in high contrast dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418952/18740320)
2. Open communication

   - Any future iterations will be adequately communicated earlier in the process (i.e. designs, experiment plans).
3. Monitoring accidental voting and other relevant data points

   - In the previous post, we saw feedback from users with >1k rep who flagged the risk of accidentally voting when checking the post score. We took a closer look at this report and pulled the following data:
   - Last month (Apr 2023), we saw 175k users who voted 870k times. Of those users, only 8% (14k users) had undone their votes.
   - **The number of posts that had votes undone only accounted for 3% of total votes.** This is the benchmark we will use moving forward.

We will continue to monitor these numbers to see if there is a noticeable uptick, and then determine if it’s a widespread issue to prioritize.

### What's next?

This change is part of a holistic exploration of the voting mechanism and what it means for everyone. Voting is an essential part of the mechanics of the platform that makes this repository of knowledge so successful. It is how we acknowledge the good work of our contributors, and we want to really explore different ways in which we can make this process more streamlined and engaging for everyone.

Year over year, we are seeing 28% fewer votes (upvotes + downvotes) and 21% fewer users voting. During our research, we also found that voting is a pain point for new users as well. In April alone, we saw:

- **72k unique users who attempted to vote 166k times** (avg 2.3 votes per user).
- **Of those 72k users, 17k users were new users** which is 24%
- This means that **1 in 4 new users attempted to vote, but could not** due to system limitations.

Because voting is one of the lowest barriers to participation, we felt that this was the best place to start to help users engage more on the platform. In the coming weeks, we have plans to roll out more ideas that we have to iterate on voting and it’s part of the user story of this site to increase engagement, so please stay tuned for those updates.

Comment: Do you have any theories, thoughts, etc, as to *why* the change caused a 28% increase over that period of time? Was the increase primarily from a specific group of users?

Comment: How did you A B test this?

Comment: @Akixkisu [Results of the vote arrows styling experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420698/results-of-the-vote-arrows-styling-experiment) (MSO)

Comment: They're not particularly pretty, and they're quite big. This might be a problem especially on mobile. **Edit**: [somebody already posted an answer about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418966/7395227)

Comment: I also regularly vote by mistake on mobile (a few times per day). Making the buttons even bigger and more prominent, will make this even more of an annoying problem.

Comment: Haven't these buttons already been in use on some of the SE sites for a while? I can remember having seen them before, a lot. Either that, or they're just very generic.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship articles and teams have been using these buttons for at least since the initial test, if not longer

Comment: @user253751 No, it's not. It's a fairly succinct way of saying that they're going to look into rolling out a variety of different features that work together instead of something piecemeal. Just because you're not comfortable using the word "holistic" doesn't make it management-speak.

Comment: @cmw it can't be that holistic if the best thing they can come up with is making the buttons uglier, instead of, say, changing reputation awards to discourage lame answers

Comment: The new buttons are terrible. No offense to whoever made them, surely it's some fancy super popular design somewhere, that's just my personal opinion. There is no reason to enclose arrow with a circle. It makes the arrow itself smaller, and overall just looking bad. And no, it's not the standard "don't like moving my cheese", that's just a much worse design, and I'm really sad it went through all the levels without someone saying "Stop this now".

Comment: @user253751 Nice shift in the goal-posts. Whether or not they conducted a holistic exploration is irrelevant to whether the phrase in question is management-speak. Careless criticism and petty resorts to questionable aesthetic taste speaks more to spite than actual constructive criticism.

Comment: @KevinB Articles? Not the blog ones. And I've never used Teams, so that's not where I've seen them. And I was not part of the expirement, either. I thought maybe on gamedev, worldbuilding, area 51, or similar.

Comment: If anyone wants to keep the old buttons, it's a good idea to contribute the colors of your favorite sites at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389361/what-are-the-selected-vote-button-colors . I'm working on a userscript to restore the old buttons, although I can't do much until the new ones are deployed.

Comment: Does the increase in votes also mean that **the votes are actually indicating quality** (or lack of it, in case of downvotes)? Because wrong-voting is way worse than no-voting (and I've seen a lot of wrong, low quality posts getting some upvotes). Increasing the number of votes means nothing if the votes are used in the wrong way (as a social media's "like", instead of a quality indicator).

Comment: What is __graduating__ an updated button styling?

Comment: In what way were the old buttons not WCAG compliant?

Comment: @Someone It looks like at least the post-voted arrow color change wasn't compliant, at least according to [their initial post on this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded).

Comment: @Quasímodo graduating a style in SE-ish means making the style appealing for new users. I do support making changes to avoid having the site freeze in old design, but not like this. This is small change, but part of many bad small changes, which make it a big problem.

Comment: @Quasímodo "Graduating" in this case means promoting [the test of this change that occurred previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded) into active use on the main site. SE experimented with this change previously, decided not to make it permanent (not to "graduate it" to usage on the public site), but are now apparently reversing course.

Comment: It must be hard to push changes on a site whose users seem so paralyzed by changes. It's a small difference in the up/down icons, I'm amazed the amount of vitriol garnered by such an arbitrary change.

Comment: @zcoop98 I've been using Stack Overflow for Teams for a couple of years now, and the voting buttons still grab my attention [every. time. I load. a page.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419171/5223757) For me, the voting buttons _need_ to not. WCAG isn't just about colour contrast; in fact, iirc recommends colour + shape (which the new design doesn't have). Since this is a logged-in-user-only distinction, then if we _can't_ fix the colour contrast for everyone, I see no reason not to put it in the High Contrast theme and call it a day. (I'm too tired to try to fight this one again.)

Comment: @rob it's the mentality of changing things for the sake of changing them (see "seagull management"). Not to mention the lame excuses for metrics. "Hey guys, our research indicates that 42% more elevator floor buttons get pushed if we remove the labels so it's not obvious which one is your floor. So we're rolling out this change across all elevators. You're welcome. No, we can't put the labels back on - what if a blind person can't read them?"

Comment: @user253751 they put a circle around an icon.. it's completely benign. I don't really follow the non sequitur about trying to confuse blind people. Thats sort of my point- all they had to do was put a circle around an icon- and users are so sensitive they go on weird tangents like that.

Comment: @rob The problem is not the icon change itself. It's the waste of resources on irrelevant things, while other things like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803) (**way** more useful IMO) are completely ignored.

Comment: Regarding the actual design of the buttons, I don't actually dislike them all that much; frankly, I think the mild distaste I do feel is more from "ew different" than the buttons actually looking bad. I'm finding it really hard to deny the fact that they are _overwhelmingly_ more "button-like" than the current arrows; maybe I'd feel differently if the current arrows, as comfy as they are, actually looked like... interactive buttons? They don't even react on hover today, much less look like anything more than static indicators to the unfamiliar. I do imagine that's a bit confusing to newcomers.

Comment: "voting is a pain point" Not yet, but it may become one. The proposed new button style looks terrible, kind of squeezes the number in between and gives far more emphasis on voting. I'm tempted to filter them out. What about giving users the choice and seeing what they choose?

Comment: @rob "...a site whose users seem so paralyzed by changes..." Maybe people feel that the current state is already close to optimal and the change is not improving things. We simply have to wait one year more and see if the new buttons make anything better. I have to admit that growing accustomed to a certain style is part for me. I'm getting older and can work well with the old style voting buttons. Maybe after using the new ones for a while it will work out the same (or better) or maybe it won't. But I don't feel overly keen on experimenting with them.

Comment: How does the last of the three bullet points relate to the previous two? First, 'attempted to vote' means tried **and failed**? Second 17k out of 72k users is 1 in 4 but that means 1 in 4 users is a new user, not 1/4 of all new users. Finally how do you define a failed attempt to vote? Upvoting is possible with zero reputation, any user can do that.

Comment: 30 second feedback: Making buttons actually look like buttons rather than indicators is good (and that'll account for the increase in use). Increasing the contrast is good. But making the actual arrows smaller is a negative.

Comment: Could the increase in voting simply be *because* they're different, and so they grab people's attention more, resulting in more upvotes because more people looked at them? If that is the case, then as soon as people get used to them, the upvote increase will decline back to what it is now, and we'll have to change the button design *again* to get back that upvote increase. At this point we might as well have a random button design each day! ;)

Comment: "a net 28% increase in overall votes" But why? You are aware of "the relay room" [Hawthorne effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawthorne_effect) yeah? Or is there a better explanation?

Comment: "*a net 28% increase in overall votes*" and also "*Year over year, we are seeing 28% fewer votes*". Is that a copy/paste error or just a strange coincidence?  In any event, I wonder if the increase in votes is merely because they are larger and draw more attention and possibly more misclicks. More research (or research transparency) is needed.

Comment: I should be allowed to turn this off in settings. I honestly don't like the buttons at all.

Comment: The buttons don't look well and also don't integrate into the current design. If you really want borders around the buttons, I'd rather put them into squares.

Comment: And I will continue to use custom CSS to restore the arrows. Old style scores in the list, arial instead of system defaults, classic arrow colors, getting rid of watched tag styles, hiding posts with ignored tags... I don't think there's any other site I have so many custom stylesheets for just to restore good UX/UI ruined by site changes.

Comment: Why do you feel the urge to make the upward and downward sign encircled? People are not blind, they can see the signs already!! Yeah, I don't like the new buttons.

Comment: How can you "attempt to vote" but not actually vote?  Either you click the button or you don't...

Comment: @Cole from my understanding, they did click the vote button but got rejected by the system due to not having enough reputation (15 rep to upvote, 125 rep to downvote)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT.  If that's the case, how is that relevant to the button redesign?  I'm also not sure why it is being called a "pain point" then either.  The reputation requirements to vote (which helps ensure high-quality votes) seem to be working as intended.  It sounds like 1:4 new users don't have enough rep to vote yet, and that is entirely by design.

Comment: @Cole it's mentioned in "What's next", which I think explained about the pain point about voting overall (according to them).

Comment: Can you A-B test either of these against the themed buttons we used to have? I liked those. Neither the bare triangles nor the circled ones compare.

Comment: @Mazura for what it's worth, the change that made inbox notifications stay there until explicitly marked as read is one of my favorite things ever. I had wanted it for years and it makes my experience on the site much more pleasant. I get many messages, as I'm sure you do, and I often see them at a time when I cannot answer, and before this change, I would forget them. Now, I can leave them unread until I have the time to deal with them properly. It is a huge improvement. So, to each their own, I guess.

Comment: I would not touch something that already works very well. There are other more important problems to be focused on, changing the style of vote buttons is easily going to make them worse imo.

Comment: I think, that is a mobile issue not a desktop issue. If you really need some improvement you may put more spaces between them. Also, it will be better if reveal of up/down works as toggle not stationary. If this is really problem, then the bookmark and activity button must be problem, too.

Comment: My objection is that it goes against good design principles. The ring increasess screen clutter. If this is to address visually challenged people then just provide them with a selectable css style.

Comment: I'm surprised by the presence of this post on Meta. There was widespread opposition to this change in the past, and this post is yet-again heavily downvoted. I hope that the staff at Stack Exchange can "read the room" and recognize that that this unpopular change is strongly rejected by the community. And I hope that the moderators can see that we, the community, respectfully would like to make it clear that these downvotes and comments show clear opposition to this change.

Comment: I find it harder to see if I've voted or not.  Also they're offensively ugly.

Comment: On top of that, regardless of the comments and answers below this post, changes just went live: seems like developers designing these like buttons completely ignored all this discussion. They probably took quite some time to come up with this design, and a lot of time was spent on experimentation, although the spent effort should not influence the decision of adoption (or not adoption)...

Comment: I can hardly tell when I've voted for something now. At least make the colours easier to read

Comment: Maybe this is an unpopular opinion, but I like these arrows. They look clean and simple. If anything I would like there to be a colour distinction between up and down arrows - a la Reddit - but this is a perfectly fine change that folks may be complaining a tad excessively about.

Comment: Aside from these round buttons not matching the SE theme (which is dominated by rectangular/angular shapes), they are rather difficult to see on Meta SO: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lwW1.png. Truth be told, I accidentally un-downvoted a post there because I couldn't tell that I'd already downvoted it.

Comment: @Lou While I may not agree with you about liking these arrows, I do see where you're coming from with the users complaining a tad excessively. The way I see it, there's a lot of bitterness coming from previous decisions SE has made, and that bitterness is being expressed in users' complaints here.

Comment: I've been around SO for a while now and unless I'm losing my mind (totally possible), wasn't this the way these buttons were styled ages ago?

Comment: @j08691 Not as far as I can tell by looking at the Web Archive, but I could be missing something...

Comment: May I suggest to at least decrease their relative dimensions (and possibly remove the circles) *after* one have voted?

Comment: So you just changed it network wide, without even telling when exactly it's being done. Not that it matters, but still, showing a lot towards how you really care (or **NOT**) for the users and the feedback they spend time to give. Huge thumbs down.

Comment: FWIW My stack app / user script restores the old vote buttons, network-wide: https://stackapps.com/questions/9443/revert-stack-exchanges-new-up-down-vote-buttons

Comment: @Phil They kind of addressed them. It's not as if they have written nothing about them, they kind of acknowledged them. They could have delivered more reasoning why they decided to push through this change nevertheless. But a promise to address something surely doesn't include any liability for taking a specific action. They were still free to decide however they want to decide. It's their site, it's their rules in the end. And some people seem to even like the new style.

Comment: I like the old design much more. Sadly, the people behind this have **definitely** seen the very negative feedback, and _most probably_ will keep the change because they have the power to do so. This is just like [YouTube making dislike counts private](https://youtu.be/kxOuG8jMIgI) – they never undid it. While I think a design change isn't that huge of a problem, it _does_ show that Stack Exchange ignores our community (and does so _loudly_). **The choice is up to all of us**: keep supporting the company, or leave and find someplace else. Personally, I'll wait it out first to see what happens.

Comment: The new design unfortunately does not let me downvote this post 1.28 times. Nothing else is circular except for the history icon. These buttons look so out-of-place in the page.

Comment: Been on the site almost daily for +10 years. Of all the "improvements" the SO geniuses have done over time, this is defently the worst. I will never like black circles with deep black arrows, and blue / orange instead of green / red. If it aint broken, dont fix it.

Comment: Bigger buttons on mobile devices are better. For people with constrained motor skills or visually challanged it allows for better usability. It probably explains the higher usage rates. This is a great move to the better for these minorities. Thanks!

Comment: "Because voting is one of the lowest barriers to participation" Penalising experienced users who downvote POOR answers is a bigger barrier.

Comment: As someone in the 8th decade of life, I find the new voting-button design to be almost incomprehensible. I sometimes have to look 2 or 3 times to see if I've voted previously on a post. Not all users are in their 20s or 30s with the ability to discern subtle visual cues. Roll this back--it's hurt accessibility for me, and I expect for many others of my age.

Comment: Well, thank you for the update! It's better contrast on buttons.

Comment: New "graduated" button is horribly cluttered, is unnecessary and unneeded. What the heck was wrong with the old button? Now we have the proverbial *"square peg in a round hole"* (actually triangle, but you get the point). It is visually unappealing and my first thought was just - "damn that is unnecessary clutter". Another fine example of something that wasn't broken being "fixed" and made worse.

Comment: I am now **really** confused. When I started looking at this "improvement", the Meta Stack Exchange buttons were equally as bad as on main Stack Overflow and all the other sites (DIY, Retrocomputing, etc.) But *now* the buttons here on Meta are actually good - flips from thin black border around a white circle with a black (or dark anyway) triangle to a dark bluish filled circle with a white triangle when I vote. *That* is clear and obvious and user-friendly. But everywhere else it is still horrible. Just take this change here and put it everywhere else and 95% of my problem with it goes away.

Comment: the new buttons yell "click me". I think they are distracting.

Comment: Have you completely validated functionality on common android browsers?  I accidentally upvoted something while using Android Chrome.  I undid my upvote, but the widget itself stayed selected, and had a color change until I touched elsewhere.  I found it confusing.

Comment: In dark mode, I'm hardly able to see these buttons and find out if I have voted already or not. White mode just isn't compatible with all other tools I use. Please revert this change and fix the goddamn mailbox instead... And I'm 20 y.o. with 100% eyesight and no color perception diseases, so this isn't even age-related (@EdM), it's just awkward design change.

Comment: It's harder for me to quickly tell if I've already voted for a post or not. The new button design kinda sucks -- definitely worse than before.

Comment: At least one comment mentioned imitating Apple's UI experience.  **Don't emulate Apple!!**  In my opinion, they stopped really caring about the user experience long ago.  **Case in point** - the Clock App: an *alarm* has snooze at the top (Top/Side  button), and *stop at the **bottom** (Home Button)*.   The *timer* has *stop at the **top** (Top/Side button)*, and repeat (a kind of snooze) at the bottom (Home).  They reverse the "Stop" on a very simple app they designed!  Horrible UI!

Comment: This is a comical mistake. The old ones were much better. Also, your use of the term "graduating" indicates that you knew it wasn't an improvement or an upgrade, and yet you released it anyway. Shame.

Comment: I find it comendable that the company Stack Exchange is willing to subject itself to this kind of public scrutinity and criticism. I gather this is embeded in the code written by the founding fathers, one of them specially, the one that left early. [The ‘Enshittification’ of TikTok | Cory Doctorow | Wired](https://www.wired.com/story/tiktok-platforms-cory-doctorow/) is a good read for the modern world.

Comment: I disliked the new arrows at first. Now I dislike it less than I did at the start. But I'm surprised something this unimportant has made the priority list at all for the product team. I guess this indicates they think this site doesn't need major changes, which in general I agree with. Are these people getting paid for their job though? If so, can I join the team? I have some programming experience and I'd love to get paid for doing little productive work. No offence intended. If they don't get paid then it makes more sense.

Comment: "Year over year, we are seeing 28% fewer votes" implies that users were voting, and then they stopped voting, as in something changed. The UI that's been constant throughout can't really be the cause of that. On the other hand, this could be explained by inefficient site workflows, decreasing site quality, and poor site policies and company decisions (as detailed across hundreds or thousands of posts on the site over the years). Changing the shape of buttons seems like rearranging the furniture on the Titanic.

Comment: For the majority of us who don't need WCAG compatible buttons, it would be nice to have an account-wide option to revert to the old design. I would be much less bothered by this change if there was an easy way for me to personally revert it.

Comment: I am moving to [Codidact](https://codidact.org/). **My comment about this was removed TWICE**. Think about it: this only shows the _censorship_ and _ignorance_ that Stack Exchange imposes on its own users. **We should not be supporting, let alone volunteering for a company like this** – there absolutely are better alternatives. _(Fun fact: I posted this and they deleted it. I posted it again, and **they deleted it a second time.**)_

Comment: Perhaps [see also.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222556/how-to-log-out-of-a-stack-exchange-site#comment1308444_268527)

Answer (score 404):

I don't really see how this is more accessible.

- The new buttons become weird ovals in Zoom Text Only mode. (The old buttons behave correctly.) At 200% zoom:

  | Before | After | Correct |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | [image: resizing only the text] | [image: also resizing the voting buttons' circle border, making it a large oval] | [image: as before, but the bookmark and timeline buttons aren't spaced out] |
- The new buttons become indistinguishable splodges when blurred. (The old buttons fare better.)

  | Before | After |
  | --- | --- |
  | [image: blurry but distinguishable] | [image: blurry and hard to see: it looks like the upvote has a down arrow] |
- The old buttons only provide feedback via a colour change, but the new buttons are no different. You should be aiming for colour + shape at a minimum. [WCAG 2.1 criterion 1.4.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#use-of-color):

  > (Level A)
  >
  > Color is not used as the only visual means of conveying information, indicating an action, prompting a response, or distinguishing a visual element.
- Changing things is *inherently* an accessibility problem. Some people find it much harder to cope with changes than others. (This is a much huger change than anything else you've changed over the past 7 years: make it count.)

  - Why does the layout need to change? It disrupts muscle memory, increases the minimum screen size required to use the site, and ruins perfectly-good [clickjacking attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).

---

The only obvious-to-me improvement is that it's more obvious that voting is possible, for people who:

- have an account;

  - with enough reputation to vote;
- didn't know they could vote;
- are familiar with this design language.

A blue dot upon earning the privilege, as was used in Documentation, might suffice *for this*; and it wouldn't [place "click me!" buttons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419171/5223757) in front of people trying to do other things<sup>1</sup> who *can't even click them*. (The adverts are bad enough.)

For people capable of ignoring them, these buttons are just going to fade into the background, eroding the very design language that you're relying on in the first place.

<sup>1: Have some webcomics: [one](https://www.monkeyuser.com/2018/focus/) [two](https://web.archive.org/web/20200314115935/https://heeris.id.au/2013/this-is-why-you-shouldnt-interrupt-a-programmer/).</sup>

---

That said, I don't understand what your goal is. You write:

> Because voting is one of the lowest barriers to participation, we felt that this was the best place to start to help users engage more on the platform.

Your company isn't valuable because people want to go on a website and vote and edit and answer and re-tag: it's valuable because those actions *result in a high-quality library*. The vast majority of people aren't here to interact with the system: they're here to get answers to their questions, and the best possible outcome for them is that the question has *already been asked and answered*.

Everything else follows from that. Everything else is *secondary* to that. And you *know* this: to quote the [new Code of Conduct (draft)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388860/308065):

> - **Answering** - The knowledge sharing of the Community is the platform's foundation. To ensure the highest quality repository of information, we have adopted quality standards that apply to all answers on our network. […]
> - **Voting** - Our voting system is central to how Stack Exchange works. Votes are how the Community signals great content and rewards its members for their contributions. Improperly cast votes undermine the integrity of the platform. […]

There is *no way* that "engagement", how I understand the word, is *actually* your goal here. Voting isn't a social media ♥  : it's a curation activity. Stack Exchange is not supposed to be *engaging*: it's supposed to be useful. I've seen far, far too many companies chase the metric of engagement<sup>2</sup> off a cliff, and destroy everything that made their offering valuable.

… which I don't believe you're doing *here*. But I still don't understand your goal, so it's hard to give useful feedback.

<sup>2: Have another webcomic: [three](http://smbc-comics.com/comic/engaged).</sup>

Comment: This is just another step towards making Stack Exchange social platform, which appears to be the final goal of the current management.

Comment: You're thinking of [WCAG Criterion 1.4.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#use-of-color): “Color is not used as the only visual means of conveying information, indicating an action, prompting a response, or distinguishing a visual element.” It's a level A criterion, which means it's part of the bare minimum low-effort stuff everyone should strive toward.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard StackOverflow stories and shorts when?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili that's the next level. First they'll remove the downvote option because it hurts the users feelings. Then change "upvote" to "like". Then give initial 10k reputation to each new users, along with removing all privileges. Then... [fill the gap]

Comment: Agree. After trying to vote up a question, which it turns out I had already upvoted, I remembered "hot meta network" had mentioned the change.  Now, the state between "you've voted" and "you've not voted" is barely distinguishable with a slight difference on gray vs blue on very thin lines.  Not impressed with the change in the least, UI people should leave well enough alone and not emulate Apple and its ever-changing Music app.

Comment: The color change is actually worse than "just" being color. I had no trouble distinguishing pressed vs non-pressed on the old buttons as the contrast between the two was pretty high, with the new buttons, however, depending on the site theme, I actually have to focus my attention on them to see the distinction :(

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard, no: SO's developers are lazy but are focusing on fixing *some other, more important* features and bugs. So, they'll probably sell SE and SO to Meta so that S()ck∊rbErg can do these for them + ruin the existing APIs, etc.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder haha. No. They are not busy fixing any bugs, they are working on the projects that give SE money, mainly Teams. It's confirmed several times by comments of staff, e.g. asked why they don't fix bugs in the new inbox, and other shiny features that now get dust and bugs. Was told by staff that "We're busy working on other projects". That was back in 2022, and I'm sure it holds true to this day, and to the last day of SE.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder as for selling, the likely buyer would be Micro$ which will use the platform as their own support forum, and help them develop new projects for free, e.g. questions by "staff" with fat rewards (rep and badges, not real money) for those who solve their problems.

Comment: The goal is, as usual, to make it seem as if SE Inc. is actually doing something, when actually they're fiddling while Rome burns.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard: I have *no problem at all* with the company prioritising Teams for the sake of profitability.  The problem is making ill-considered changes to SO, for post-hoc rationalisations, that undermine what make it successful.

Comment: "it's valuable because those actions result in a high-quality library" - no no, new user growth, that's the only value that exists

Comment: Not really sure if I up-circled you already or not, but I know I smacked it once for each of your three all-too-relatable webcomics, so if my math holds true you just got another upvote. Note that I up-circled your answer for the content, not the improved experience these new buttons offered me...

Comment: @StelioKontos You know, I think that's the first compliment I've ever got for my excessive linking of things. Thank you for letting me know you liked it. :-)

Comment: Precisely: "Our voting system is central to how Stack Exchange works. Votes are how the Community signals great content..."  Upvoting an answer means it's useful (which should *only* be done when one **knows** it's useful (by trial or experience).  But upvoting a question is really more of a 'I have this question too' - a *much lower criteria*.   **If** you want to increase engagement and/or address the "one in four" lacked voting privileges, then *allow new users (rep 1) to **upvote questions** immediately*.  **And** that might help reduce duplicate questions.

Comment: @Randall Mind if I steal that for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389576/308065)? That's an _excellent_ suggestion, and deserves more visibility.

Comment: Please do!  Glad you like it!  Also @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica mentioned Apple [earlier in these comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows/389458?noredirect=1#comment1299147_389458).  I expanded on that in [this other comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows/389458?noredirect=1#comment1301353_389359); you can steal that, too, in case you feel that brief case study is useful in emphasizing a point  :-)
(And thanks for asking)

Comment: Also - I didn't know about "Zoom Text Only." Is that just changing the `font size` setting in the browser, or a specific setting somewhere?

Comment: @Randall It's a specific setting. In desktop Firefox, it's in the menu bar (can be shown by tapping "Alt"), and on Chromium-based browsers it's tucked away in the settings page somewhere.

Comment: I found the "Zoom Text Only" setting for my browser along with zooming, but I wasn't able to reproduce the "weird oval" issue. I suppose it has been fixed. As for blurring: is this just intended as a simulation of the effect of poor eyesight? Or just what?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Which browser were you testing in? I've reproduced in Firefox (slightly visible at 200%, very visible at 300%). And yes, it's intended as that.

Comment: @Randall "immediately" in the sense of "at 1 rep", sure; but please not in the sense of "as soon as the question has been asked". Most questions are quite poorly asked, *especially* the ones that new users might care about, and they desperately need a review period first.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Ah, I just didn't zoom far enough. (I find it obnoxious dealing with scrolling a page with very large text.) The triangle is drawn using SVG, and there doesn't seem to be any text involved at all, so I'm at a loss to explain the distortion.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - "as soon as the question has been asked" is not what I had in mind at all.  Rather, that a 'rep 1' user could vote up *other* folk's questions that have been asked *previously* and are relevant to him.  Ideally, one of those past questions would solve his problem too.  Regardless, the new question queue is definitely *not* the place to sit and vote up every question posted, especially for a new user.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Hardly excessive. Unless you put big circles around the links, then maybe... ;)

Answer (score 191):

A 28% increase is not necessarily a positive outcome. Perhaps more users voted without having read the content properly.

The "holistic exploration of the voting mechanism" similarly sounds like you are aiming for engagement, not quality.

How are you going to ensure that vote counts reflect post quality?

Comment: That I think is irrelevant to the post, there is no specification here if the users did make as you said perhaps as well. However, I think that more votes *normally* equate to a better quality experience on the site. There are much much more people who don't vote at all than people who vote incorrectly, so the prior is a bigger problem to fix at the moment. I really like Mad Scientest's answer in this case: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389367/790695

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan I'm sorry, but I don't understand the first sentence of your comment. You then assert that "more votes normally equate to a better quality experience" without giving evidence; furthermore, I'm not talking about the quality of the experience, but quality assurance of content. Finally, it may be true that there are more people not voting than voting ill-informedly, but that simply does not mean that the former is a bigger problem. My answer is terse; if you need more details, perhaps see the final section of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389458/205264.

Comment: There are many posts across the SE network that go without votes of either kind and, as mentioned in the post, voting has been declining year over year. This makes it harder for users to find value on the platform because they are less able to  quickly judge the quality of the content. Encouraging more voting supports curation across the network, making it easier for users to locate high quality questions and answers.

Comment: I'm agree with this. Currently, the voting button is much more larger, deeper, and more prominently than the post itself. So I think it does push people to give some random votes regardless of the quality of the post, simply because they would see the vote button first but the then the post content.

Comment: @Sasha that does not address the concerns I’m describing or the question at the end. Am I not making myself clear?

Comment: The justification of "a net 28% increase in overall votes" was deemed to be correlated and a desired thing.  FYI this is how our paperclip-maximizing AI overlords will run the world too.

Comment: @Sasha If I had to guess, I would suggest the decrease in voting may be because a lot of important questions have been asked and answered. Often when I use the site, if I find a good answer to my question that is already highly voted I just grab the answer and move on with my work. I often only vote if I find an amazing answer or if the good answer is in close competition with bad answers.

Answer (score 158):

Looks like the new buttons were recently released fully. They look *awful*; this does not look like an improvement at all.

> [image: Screenshot of new vote buttons]

...Yuck.

The preview showed they were ugly, but in the implementation, they look even worse.

They are big, they are obtrusive, the arrows seem too small for the circle, and they don't go with the rest of the page at all. There are too many circles now.

Increasing (thoughtful!) voting is a good idea, but this monstrosity is probably not the way to go. Maybe make more voting-badges, create Meta posts encouraging users to vote, or do something else constructive. But these buttons are the equivalent of ruining a skyline with one of those big, blocky, gray buildings, and... *blech*.

Comment: +1. In fact, at least you can note your vote (the color change). But in meta sites, it only appears as a thin dark circumference around the arrow (albeit with a mild contrast change inside) which is, at best, not distinct enough to be perceived.

Comment: They're also not centered, in more ways than one. the outline is too thin/light and difficult to see in some circumstances, making it appear as though we simply have smaller buttons now.

Comment: "Maybe make more voting-badges, create Meta posts encouraging users to vote, or do something else constructive" The most constructive thing you can do is to actually improve the buttons, which is what they did. If people don’t use your interface, the very first thing to do is to improve that interface, not to throw them a manual on how to use it. I personally find the new arrows way better because it’s easier to see they are actual buttons.

Comment: @bfontaine - I disagree with you on the 'way better' part, but thanks for explaining your downvote.

Answer (score 145):

Maybe if you tried a community of 100,000+ UX specialists, you would gain some surprising insights. If only such a [community existed somewhere](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)...

PS: If these buttons serve as an accessibility solution, I wonder which accessibility guidelines you are following. It appears that those of us who actually work in accessibility use something different. Moreover, visual accessibility is not the sole type of accessibility that exists. I highly doubt these buttons pass most neurological accessibility tests and they will probably fail at quite common conditions like Autism and OCD. Show this

[image]

to someone with OCD (and many autist people) and see the world burn. (thank you @wizzwizz4 for the image)

**EDIT:** Any UX apprentice knows that the image below is a perfect example of cognitive overload. It is typically taught at the early stages of one's career.

[image]

with vote up

[image]

Comment: Fine words, pity they're thrown on a blank wall. (Yes they ask for feedback. No, they don't really do anything with it, when it's against their decision. Nothing will revert the decision to uglify the buttons, not even if every single UX expert in the world will personally tell them how horrible it is.)

Comment: yes I know, it's not my first rodeo with SE. But I felt the need to say it anyway.

Comment: Your post has me questioning whether or not I have OCD or maybe am developing it as a reaction to these new buttons.

Comment: I noticed that the "after" new vote button image in your screenshots does not have a vote arrow button voted on, unlike the "before" image. This makes it a poor comparison. I suggest changing the "after" image to be like the "before" image, which is of an upvoted post.

Comment: I genuinely don't believe the pixel pushers coming up with these changes actually use any of the SE sites.

Comment: At least this one is blue. On meta.so, it's grey, and a very light gray so that you have to peer closely at it to figure out which one has been selected.

Comment: I totally agree that making the arrow images smaller is ... stupid for those with impaired vision.  But I do like the circle on the new arrows; make a button... look like a button.  Yes, those who have been around a while know they are buttons, but a little hint helps everyone.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the points about "neurological accessibility", and would need them spelled out to evaluate this properly. However, I do find the low-contrast circular outlines around the unclicked circles to be visually distracting/obnoxious, and I am pretty sure that I am... not entirely neurotypical; so....

Answer (score 141):

I agree with many of the other commenters here stating that the buttons are ugly and a strict downgrade. I find it hard to see how they are somehow more accessible, given that the arrow itself is much smaller and harder to see.  I also take issue with changing something so fundamental about the SE experience, those buttons are arguably more iconic than the SO logo itself.

I also seriously question the 28% increase metric.  Are you sure this isn't due to some other confounding factor (e.g. overall increased participation due to the pandemic)?

Edit: Given how significant of a change this is, I would also really appreciate an account wide option to revert the buttons to the old design when logged in. WCAG is fine, but if I personally don't need it then it seems reasonable to have an option to use the buttons that have existed since the inception of the site.

Comment: I think their experiment was flawed because it assigned existing users to the AB groups. The thought of an existing user when seeing a new button was probably: "Uh oh a new button, let's see what happens if I click it". Thus an increase in voting. A much fairer way to test it would be to only assign new users to the AB groups, i.e. users who have never been exposed to any voting button.

Comment: Are you suggesting that existing users would have no idea what the buttons do, despite them being in the same place and similar in appearance to the old buttons? I agree that users who couldn't figure that out probably aren't worthwhile collecting the votes of.

Comment: @StuartF no, I'm not suggesting that the existing users would have no idea what the buttons do. But they would clearly notice the new design and would be curious how the design responds to clicking the button.

Answer (score 101):

> We’ve heard your feedback from the previous posts about this change, and are not moving forward until we address them.

You've moved forward. Have you *really* addressed them?

Comment: For those wondering what the duck is for, it's a powerful-if-rather-tenuous metaphor, reflective of the fact that not everything in an SE post can be considered to have any weight.

Answer (score 73):

I honestly did not have a strong opinion on this change until it was finally in effect on my devices. And now it is crystal clear that it is several magnitudes worse than what was previously in place.

- If the intent was to make it clear that the voting buttons are buttons, then it is something that does not contribute to the experience of existing participants who already know about them and how to use them, which amounts to almost all users with an account. This is even explained in the tour, which we expect new users to see. It almost makes it sound like you want to signal visitors without an account to vote more often, which we know is not that useful right now... Right?
- It's *less usable*, because it's now harder to grasp whether I already voted on a post. The original announcement showing how the button looks like when selected was only presented in the non-dark Stack Overflow theme, seemingly disregarding how it would look like in dark mode and in other sites of the network. I have the impression that the colors employed in the selected choice do not contrast enough with the unselected buttons, and it's a bit worse here on Meta Stack Exchange, on Meta Stack Overflow, and on the main Stack Overflow in dark mode. Even this particular announcement did not show how the buttons would look when selected, so it seems to me that a lot of folks out of the A/B selection wouldn't really be able to understand what would happen before it went live.

I have the sentiment that this roll-out will catch many people off-guard. Primarily from the part described above: we weren't sure of what we were getting. And also from the fact that we should expect better design from a company hosting one of the most important online platforms for programmers.

Comment: *"It almost makes it sound like you want to signal visitors without an account to vote more often, which we know is not that useful right now... Right?"* well, they can't currently, anyway, though i suspect that won't be the case soon.

Comment: I am constantly getting my attention drawn away from the user-posted content, and thinking "wait, did I already vote on this question/answer?". Having to look at and think about something that used to stay in the background isn't good.

Comment: I have the same problem - it is hard to see whether I have already voted or not.

Comment: Not just difficult on SO meta, arqade meta has the same problem. Pretty much impossible to see if I've voted at a glance 

Comment: Two posts related to the same issue: [I can't see if I've already voted on something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389668) and [It’s hard to tell how I’ve voted on meta sites. Please make selected and unselected vote buttons different colors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389563).

Comment: "you want to signal visitors without an account to vote more often, which we know is not that useful right now" - that's a separate issue; it *would* be useful, particularly to curators, if there were proper mechanisms to see that "anonymous feedback" readily. And ironically it may actually be higher quality: those votes on SO are typically only about 60% positive, while registered votes are over 90% positive. (Of course, the latter figure has a bias because users between 15 and 125 reputation can upvote but not downvote.)

Answer (score 70):

Why ask the community for feedback if you are just going to ignore it?

As a protest, I will not be voting any longer until this change is reverted, or at the very least made optional.

Comment: I'm torn on whether I should upvote your post or not :D

Comment: @PixelMaster Even if you did, would you be able to see the vote?

Comment: The protest the must be massive in order for it to work

Comment: @PixelMaster - I'm upvoting Foo's post by proxy of upvoting your comment since there aren't any circles around comment voting buttons... YET!

Comment: At least they left the comment upvote icon alone!

Answer (score 69):

I appreciate the A/B testing. If the 28% increase in voting engagement is accurate, then it sounds like a big win.

However, the design is pretty "meh" in my opinion. The buttons are generic and lack branding, like something I'd see in a cheap hotel elevator or one of the dozens of knock-off SO sites. Maybe it's clearer that those are buttons, not just decoration, but I'm curious if any other designs were tested? Perhaps something that is a bit more uniquely identifiable with SO?

Comment: This was something I thought about too. The buttons don't match SO's design and branding at all; I don't like the direction this is headed...

Answer (score 61):

I want to say that I think a big barrier to voting is that the place where the learning happens is not the place where the voting happens.

When I go to stack overflow from google I immediately scroll away from the question and into the answers. I will likely never return to the top of the page and will therefore never see the voting buttons. No matter what they look like. And when I am reading an entry (whether a question or an answer) it is frequently long. And even if the buttons are still visible on my monitor, my eyes are now at the bottom of the page and moving on to reading the next answer.

In these scenarios the voting arrows are no longer part of my view. There is no call to action for me to use them.

Perhaps it would be useful to add a supplementary upvote/downvote at the bottom of the question/answer, near to where the username avatar and rep appear. This way you would see them as soon as you finished reading and may be reminded to vote.

PS: I would like to add that I think a 28% increase in voting makes sense simply because the buttons are different. We notice things that are different and are therefore reminded to use them. I would theorize that changing the buttons in any way whatsoever will cause voting to increase temporarily, and then go back to baseline as soon as people become used to the new design.

Comment: I use [a userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md#post-headers--question-toc) to make the [voting arrows sticky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAc0H.gif) for this exact reason! Posts don't have to be that long to push the vote buttons out of view... I would be super interested to see what effect this would have on voting if it was tested on the real site.

Comment: I've used blog-ish sites that had this. The only downside on Stack Overflow is that it'd make big horizontal gaps on the page. zcoop98's approach helps with that, but then it's _much_ harder to not-look at the post score.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 would you believe it, there's also [a userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/HideVoteCounts.user.js) for that...

Comment: @wizzwizz4 why would you want to not look at the post score?

Comment: @Someone If I want to judge based on the content, and I don't currently have the ability not to let the score affect my judgement.

Comment: "Perhaps it would be useful to add a supplementary upvote/downvote at the bottom of the question/answer" - But *please **don't*** have the top buttons just scroll down with the answer!  I find that to be very distracting behavior, especially when the browser's screen updates bog down.

Comment: "When I go to stack overflow from google I immediately scroll away from the question and into the answers." Why would you not want to make sure that the question is *suitable to what you're trying to figure out*, before trying to parse the answers?

Comment: who cares if the question is suitable if the answer solves my problem

Answer (score 53):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On the Meta for math.se, a vote doesn't change the arrow from black to blue, you just get the pencil-thin ring, and maaayyyybe a shade of grey - hard to be sure about that.

Is this intentional?

Edited to add: Yup, this is getting really irritating. It used to be that I could revisit an older post with recent activity, and just glance at an answer and see that I'd already voted on it, and move on to other parts of the page. Now, I just can't tell. You are wasting my time, and a lot of other people's time too.

The responses to the arrow change seem to be spread over multiple Meta posts. Does anyone know if there's even been an acknowledgement, like "Okay, we are aware of this, and are figuring out a fix"?

Comment: Same at CV meta and in fact all meta sites that I am aware of. This is really unrecognizable.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention. Our team is working on updating the colors of the button after voting on Meta sites so it will be much more visible.

Comment: @Sasha - Thanks for the reply.

Comment: This issue should now be fixed for all the Meta sites across the network.

Comment: Thank you, Sasha. Do you know if there are any plans for any fixes on the main/non-meta sites? Math.se is still kinda hard to distinguish.

Comment: @Sasha: why fix it on meta and not on all other sites?

Comment: @MartinArgerami more details on that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389771/1324540

Answer (score 52):

With the change, it feels like the buttons are more important than the actual vote count. They're humongous and the padding and roundness remind me of Material Design 3. Then somehow the vote count either is or looks a lot smaller; it's pretty confusing and the design seems counterintuitive.

From a (unqualified) designer's perspective this does not seem to match the look and feel of SE sites. I understand that the purpose is to increase voting interaction, but just because one design does what you need means you should definitely use it. I imagine alternative designs that may have the same effect.

Just an example of a random idea, what if the original design was used, but when not pressed you use an outline? This makes it more obvious that the element can be clicked.
[image: vote btn]

Answer (score 52):

With the new buttons live across the network, in my opinion, they look awful and distracting. Some observations:

- As others have noted, the **circles feel like added elements to parse**. So whereas the "traffic light" of widgets next to each post used to be 6 things, now it conceptually feels like 8 things (just on the bad side of the [magic number seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two)).
- In the *unclicked* state, the **circles are so thin and dim they disappear** at certain angles of my eye to the screen, and re-appear at others. So as I scan the page there's a distracting shimmering effect as the circles come & go from visibility in the corner of my eye.
- In the *clicked* state, the **button colors match the site theme which may not provide contrast**. For example, on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) they're brick red which is pretty visible (to me), whereas on [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/26517/can-this-be-a-better-way-of-defining-subsets) they're a dark blue, which is harder to distinguish from the unclicked gray (to me). In combination, I have to track a different feel as I browse different sites on the network. And I bet somewhere on the network there's a site where the theme matches the unclicked gray exactly (who knows)? I'm pretty stunned that the only distinction between on & off is the color; I thought that was a canonical bad practice for accessibility.
- The appearance **conflicts with the comment voting buttons on the same page**. Previously all the voting buttons were synchronized, now they're not. The comment buttons are still solo-arrows that get darker when clicked. The new q/a vote buttons have these big circles, the arrows relatively smaller and swimming inside, with upvotes noted by a color change (which may or may not be a tonal change depending on the site theme).

The overall effect is actually much worse than I would have expected before the general roll-out, ouch.

Comment: I also want to add that because of the new buttons, it is inconvenient to view the total number of votes "for" and "against"

Comment: Re pt. 2 - I have the feeling this design was fathomed on a state-of-the-art color-callibrated 4K OLED monitor.

Answer (score 47):

This is actually a total failure of accessibility on Stack Overflow.

Perhaps I am slightly color-blind, but for that very reason the new buttons are not accessible to me. I can no longer make out how *I* have voted, if at all, on the given item.

In the past, if I had voted up or down on an item, that vote arrow was drawn very differently in a way that was completely obvious and attention-getting. But in the new way of drawing, there is *no* discernible difference (to me) between, say, an up arrow where I have not voted on this item and an up arrow where I have upvoted this item.

Comment: If it's so then maybe I am colorblind too or maybe it's really everyone's issue. Things really have messed up.

Answer (score 43):

I want to acknowledge everyone who has indicated that with the new buttons it is harder to tell whether you have already voted on something or not. This is an issue that makes it harder to engage on the platform, which we take seriously. We saw that this problem was especially prevalent on the Meta sites because they use grayscale.

We just rolled out a change across Meta sites on the network, making it much more obvious to see that you have voted on a question or answer. Now, after you have voted the whole button should appear dark, rather than just the outer ring, with the arrow inside appearing lighter.

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

If you find a meta site where the updated style is not live, please let us know so we can address it.

On the network sites (excluding Meta) the coloration of the voting buttons varies based on the theme of the site, so they don’t look the same everywhere. If there are specific sites where you are finding the same problem of visibility after voting, please let us know in the comments here.

Comment: Every beta-themed site. You _really_ can't address this by making incremental changes… but thanks for trying, I guess. It's better than _not_ doing anything.

Comment: Oh, it's also a problem on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I browse almost exclusively using my Samsung phone's dark theme. Unfortunately, with these new buttons it's now almost impossible for me to see when I've voted on a greyscale meta site post. This is particularly problematic because it's *very* easy to accidentally vote when scrolling, and now I'm unlikely to notice such accidental votes.

Comment: A similar change is needed for [Chess.SE](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) and [OR.SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/) as it is difficult to tell if one has already voted or not.

Comment: The same issue also applies to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The "I voted" arrows on cooking.stackexchange.com have a pale pink background that is nearly invisible on TN screens (and is probably invisible to people with red-green colorblindness).

Comment: This might help, but I can't help thinking just how much more ugly it looks with this update. What was so wrong with the original vote arrows anyways...

Comment: Problem on https://biology.stackexchange.com/ main site, too. Please fix.

Comment: Using the dark theme on phones completely messes up the vote buttons and it's almost impossible to tell whether I have voted on something or not. A middle-ground design which would've highlighted the vote arrows instead of the circles around them (keeping the circles from the new design) would've worked better. But anyway...

Comment: Pretty much everywhere needs a fix like Meta - e.g., diy.stackexchange.com retrocomputing.stackexchange.com electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: That doesn't help on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is still a problem for https://music.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks everyone for reporting the sites where this continues to be an issue. We are keeping track of this.

Comment: @Sasha: A month later, this is still a problem — I have reasonable eyesight, and on multiple network sites (as linked in comments on this answer), it remains very difficult to see the button status.

Comment: @PLL Thanks for adding your thoughts, we are aware that this is an ongoing issue. I don't have any updates to share on this at the moment unfortunately, but we are keeping track of the concerns people have raised and which sites are affected.

Answer (score 42):

No, things do *not* always look better when you put them in a circle.

The new buttons are badly designed and other answers explained why pretty well. What's more disturbing is this appears to be a solution in search of a problem nobody asked for, whereas *real issues* with disappearing plus/minus signs when the vote count exceeds hundreds, or relentlessly requested literacy in using a **proper minus sign** `−` in place of a hyphen `-` are ignored for a decade:

- [Replace hyphen in front of scores/reputation by minus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124216)
- [Negative vote counts should use Minus Sign (U+2212) instead of Hyphen-Minus (U+002D)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71269)

Before making superficial updates (which for many turn out to be downgrades), please make sure the site content is displayed competently and is in agreement with good typographic practices and standardized notations, and not with what is easy for your designer team to implement or is aligned with their current mood.

Comment: This answer needs better visibility!

Answer (score 39):

For those who want it, I have once again made a user style to revert the vote buttons to an approximation of the way they were before. You can find it [here](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/userscripts/raw/main/SE%20Voting%20Fix.user.css). If I got anything wrong, don't hesitate to [open an issue](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/userscripts/issues)!

Comment: Maybe you could remove the `.question` prefix so it also works on answers?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Done.

Comment: Seems to work great! Personally I'm using a lighter gray: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Nrx.png

Comment: Great work. I've made the following changes for myself: Added `font-weight: unset !important;` to the `.js-vote-count`, to get rid of the bold text, setting the `--fs-subheading` variable to 1.9em on the container to restore the font size, I've overridden `--black-400` to `#babfc4` to restore the gray color and finally I've set the arrow sizes to 34px.

Comment: Actually, I went through archive.org and discovered that the original font size was `1.61538462rem`, so I've set it to that wonderful number instead :)

Comment: @MMM I've incorporated these changes into the main script. Hopefully it didn't break anything :p

Comment: "Stylus failed to parse usercss: Could not find metadata." for your "here" link. I had to click your "open an issue" link, navigate to the file, manually copy-paste it into Stylus's editor, and then click "Overwrite Style" in the import dialog that popped up to parse out the "applies to site..." filters. Probably a good idea to point that out to Stylus users so they don't get confused at Stylus recognizing it as a style but failing to parse it.

Answer (score 37):

Regardless of taste, if this is the final design of the buttons, personally I see some adjustments at the perceptual level that can be improved.

The contiguous circles perceptually emphasize the central axes where they are located. This causes that in centered alignments, elements with irregular optical areas, such as the numbers 4, 7, and negatives, seem to be off center.

[image]

[image]

To avoid this, it would be enough to reinforce other virtual alignment axes. For example, in square buttons, the importance becomes of the lateral margins instead of the central axis, disguising the off-center effect:

[image]

The middle term between one option and another is explained in [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/142518/115107), where the use of squircles (no circle, no square) decreases the strength of any kind of emergent virtual axis:

[image]

Comment: I was going to comment the same, Had even few screenshots ready. The last pair of buttons look much better IMHO

Comment: Even when circles are not used, there is still the line obtained by extending the height of the two triangles. In all the shown screenshots, I notice that negative numbers are off-center, but the effect is even more noticeable when squares are used, probably because the squares are more clearly delimiting a zone.

Comment: The effect is the most noticeable with squircles to me.

Answer (score 32):

The text showing the numeric score is now smaller. This matters not just for readability (it's one of the most important bits of data about a post!) but also because clicking on the number shows the breakdown of upvotes and downvotes.

It's highly unusual for "accessibility" to be cited as a reason for making important text smaller, or for making an interactable element smaller.

Answer (score 29):

I've created a [userscript](https://gist.github.com/12944qwerty/0803a840748049300d225358439b6789) for anyone who may want to revert this change. Lemme know if something goes wrong with it and I'll try fixing ASAP.

Comment: Mostly works, but sometimes this happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xyMw.png

Comment: @Butthosenewbuttonsthough.. bro you changed your username for this

Comment: I have a problem. I use Stack Overflow in high-contrast dark mode, but all the vote buttons have boxes around them.

Answer (score 26):

If this is about accessability, it could have been done better (refer to other answers).

If this is about generating votes, I suggest to create a new privilege: After giving fifty votes, you are allowed to return to the old button design.

Answer (score 24):

While I realize that not everyone will like every change that's introduced, at the very least a new feature should be getting mixed reactions - ideally the majority should be positive. Currently, this post is the <strike>11th</strike> 5th most downvoted of all time here on meta only a few days after rolling out the new buttons.

**Please revisit the community's feedback and (at least temporarily) *roll back this change.***

Comment: Although I agree that this should be reverted, I'm afraid it won't. I mean, they didn't revert [this](/q/375081/401803), [this](/q/368285/401803) and [this](/q/372049/401803) (all in the top 15 all-time most downvoted), so there's no reason to believe it'll be different this time. We'd better stop wasting our time in Meta, because the company doesn't care about our feedback (they just pretend they do, but it's obvious that they don't)

Answer (score 17):

I think the update is pointless. And it will not encourage users to vote more. All that has changed is that the buttons have become larger (although they were normal size before), but they have become ugly and very poorly combined with the design of StackExchange sites.

And it also annoys me that I have to click on this terrible button to vote against this post.

#### Update:

You have seen a negative reaction from the community (+124/
-673). You have been pointed out a lot of shortcomings of the new buttons, of which you have fixed only one!

Answer (score 15):

On locked posts, the new bold font hasn't been applied. Like on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61142/about-your-fing-website) question:

> [image]

It still has the old font, not the strange, new one that we have now:

> [image]

I'd say I wanted them to be consistent, but I really *don't*, because they're ugly. But it probably should be fixed.

Oh, and while you're at it, maybe you can fix [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359069/votes-label-isnt-centered-on-locked-posts-with-an-extreme-score) related issue, where high-scored lock-posts have un-centered scores.

Comment: Okay. The more we are noting, the more we are able to conclude the inevitable: the design implementation is a disaster.

Comment: In which way is the new font "strange"?

Comment: @apaderno - in that it is new and unfamiliar and that I, for whatever reason, don't like it. Hence, _strange_.

Comment: Why is bold even considered to be better here?  Bold is used to offset a piece of text from the rest of its context.  There's **no context** around the number.  If you want it more visible, change the SIZE.

Comment: @Randall font weight (bold-ness) does impact on perceptual contrast, and therefore visibility. Being able to improve visibility while maintaining compactness is useful. Using bold text isn't *just* about context; there's a reason we have both boldface and italic (and other forms of emphasis, such as underline) as standard typographic tools.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In the images CDR pasted, I find the '146' more readable than the '-139' (grey color notwithstanding).  Maybe it's just the way he copied/pasted it.  Bold can effectively reduce the kerning between characters, which was a significant part of what I had in mind.  I'm no font wiz, but the fonttype might also make a big difference here.

Answer (score 15):

The change is live now and my first impression is that yes, the voting buttons are more obvious and I can understand more people using them but at the same time the score has become less obvious to decipher. For me as experienced user I already know where the voting buttons are, but I need to see the score frequently. That became harder. My association is two big balloons with something small squeezed in between. It may just be me being used to the old design but I find it more pleasing aesthetically.

Some concrete feedback:

- the circles edges are too emphasized
- the arrows are too small
- the circles are too big
- the colors are too similar

Hope that helps you in case you ever want to redesign the feature. Btw. just discovered again that it still says "X votes" instead of score but one can get used to a lot. I will need to come back in a month/year and recheck my impression.

I guess it could be that the novelty effect of these voting buttons has worn off by then. I also didn't understand why voting is/was a pain point. People missed the arrows? Maybe they simply would have needed to be reminded of the feature a few times if they didn't vote.

Answer (score 15):

What I specifically dislike about the change is the lack of contrast on many sites, for example https://scifi.stackexchange.com:

[image]
[image]

The difference between the regular colour and "I already voted on this" is just too small; I already accidentally upvoted things more than once by accident.

I actually have fairly good vision, but I'm typing this in in the evening with my screen fairly dim, so it seems like a fairly serious accessibility problem (which is ironic since that was one of the main reasons for this change!) On full brightness it's probably a bit clearer, although still not spectacularly so.

On Stack Overflow it's orange instead of light blue, which is a bit better, though still not brilliant. On https://meta.stackexchange.com it also sets the background colour:

[image]
[image]

And that's much better, IMHO.

(While some other answers already touch on this aspect a little bit, I felt it was worth pointing out in a separate answer – personally I don't really care about most of the other criticisms, and would hardly have even noticed the design changed if it wasn't for this).

Comment: I agree. I feel like the inverse color effect of meta (dark background and white arrow) should be used everywhere. To me it seems like the current effect used on non-meta sites looks more like a hover effect than an indicator of already having voted.

Answer (score 15):

Since the Product Team wanted numbers, here's some numbers:

**Problem #1:** How do we make a triangle more accessible to the vision-impaired users (near/far-sightedness, visual agnosia, color blindness, etc)?

**Solution:** Make the vote icon less than one third the previous size, and draw a pretty circle around it. It's actually closer to one fourth the former size, but you get the point...

**Numbers:** The total surface area of the upvote/downvote arrow icons went from 264px² to 76.5px²: that's a 71% *reduction* in size of the one entire visually-identifiable element used to know whether you're about to upvote or downvote something. Hate to break it to you, but no matter how you spin it, that circle without the trusty triangle infers literally *nothing* about what will happen when you click, tap, or press it.

[image: Vote arrow size back when accessibility must've sucked][image: Vote arrow size with accessibility enhancements applied]

Furthermore, in the world I live in, which happens to feel very real, the only way these updated vote buttons will actually have a predictable outcome on a user's voting habits in a deterministic manner is if you add the classic MW2 hit marker sound to your onClick event and hope they have their speakers on.

**Problem #2:** How do we make our tiny but emboldened circled triangle more accessible to the physically-imparied users (DCD, hand tremors, age-related motor control decline, fat fingers, etc)?

**Solution:** Increase the size of the button (circle and all) by 5px because the intern just remembered that adding a circle also means adding margins or the whole UI begins to look like a broken record.

**Numbers...** Previous clickable area was 36 * 36 = 1296px². New clickable area, using πr² with a radius of 19.5 for the circle excluding the border width, we arrive at 1195px². Which is a mind boggling 101px² smaller than before. Bigger button, smaller hittable region.

So in other words, not only can you not eat your cake, but you can't have it either.

At least it's accessible.

Comment: No arguments against actual figures. Good job.

Answer (score 15):

As a person who sits on advisory committees for persons with disabilities in a major Canadian city, I really have to ask; How many visually impaired people were consulted during the process of deciding to overhaul the UI?

As several other people have mentioned, these circles are making it harder for people with visual impairments to understand what they are looking at. As voting is an essential part of how content gets moderated on ALL SE sites, its very disturbing to know that people with visual impairments will have a harder time being part of that process as a result of this overhaul.

Changing things for the sake of changing them is one issue in itself, but making major changes to the visual layout of an entire network of websites without consulting people with disabilities, is a beyond concerning.

Want to help make the lives of people with disabilities easier? Consult with us, hire us, talk to us. We are always in need of a voice.

### Disabled people exist.

Comment: +1 - Here, here, [my point exactly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390425/280335).

Answer (score 14):

Why, I'm thrilled about our new and improved voting graphics! It's nice of you  to provide some diversionary entertainment while we are experiencing the [moderator strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/196834).

By the way... remind me, what is that Code-of-Conduct rule one violates if one degrades the network site's UI against the overwhelming objections and protest of the users? Oh wait, I guess there isn't any such rule.

Answer (score 14):

I can see the style has been modified since this was posted. Both hover and clicked button styles differ much more substantially, making it much more readable. Despite there is even more contrast than before, I somehow find it more harmonizing with the whole page, in comparison to what was proposed originally.

[image]

I think this was my biggest remark, and perhaps I can retract my downvote now.  Please propagate this to other SE sites!

For example, on Music SE the buttons look like this:

[image]

It somehow lacks contrast, and I need to look twice to see if I have clicked a button or not. Also, on my FHD screen the circle actually looks pixelated, the top, bottom, left and right edges look thinner, and overall the impression is not pleasing. It doesn't seem to affect the light gray unclicked button, but the darker line clicked one looks jagged. The filled button (as here, in the Meta site), looks much better.

Some sites, like Physics SE example shown below, use color, but I'm afraid this is of little help to colorblind people.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I have realized that there is another state that I have been considering posts to be in: "Not (yet) engaged with". And previously, those posts had nicely greyed-out up and down arrows, which very well reflected their status wrt me.

I know you went ahead with this change in part because it increased the number of votes. Well, I'm mostly on math.se, and on most posts my opinion would be fairly uninformed - I shouldn't be voting on them. And now I'm getting poked "vote, vote, vote", as intended.

Listen, I know what you want is "more", while what I want is "better", and this isn't enough of of an irritation to make me stop using math.se, and like all modern irritations it'll eventually become ignorable and ignored. But it's not appreciated.

Comment: Even SE needs to realize some day that in the long run, only "better" leads to "more", so let's assume we are on the same side.

Comment: There's plenty of money to be made with "low quality / high volume".

Answer (score 12):

The buttons have 100% opacity by default; they look selected when they aren't. The circles also make the arrows way too small.

Answer (score 12):

As many other users, I find the new design of voting buttons not quite appealing. But that is not a serious problem for me.

What is worse about them is that since the buttons have occupied a larger area on the screen, the area for the text of a question or an answer has reduced. I don't bother about PCs and laptops as I use SE mostly on mobile device. But the size of the default text has surely diminished a bit which forces me to zoom in the page. However, after zoom in, the page starts looking rather odd and other features of the site will vanish off the edges due to zoom. Also re-adjusting text size for the browser itself is not a good alternative as it will cause too large text for sites other than those of Stack Exchange network.

The new style buttons might not have been bad but what makes it worse (at least for me) is that it costed the default size of the text.

Answer (score 9):

The new design has a bad developer experience (dx). the developer can't focus on the content.

As a developer, it attracts my eyes, but I can't focus on the real content. (it's distracting / annoying).

The picture below (no circle border) is a clean design and developer experience (dx) (no distraction, so we can focus on content):
[image]

(Note that for accessibility, the circle can still be there on hover state, the circle border is just transparent in normal state. or you can make the buttons a bit bigger, like prev design, so there will be no need for a circle on hover state.)

And the below one (circle border) is a bad design and a bad developer experience (dx) (it always has an extra attention to the buttons, so we can't focus on content):

[image]

Aside from the dx, the design is also not suitable. the simple big circle doesn't fit to the rest of design (it doesn't have harmony, and it's odd looking). the ui may seem beauty, but for the long period and this usecase, it's not a clean solution.

Comment: That "dx" you're talking about? That's just UX. :-P Developer experience would normally mean the experience of the people developing _this_ website (i.e., the people using Stacks and C#).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Hey. DX (developer experience) means the experience of a developer. (Like : "Developer experience is the overall feeling and experience of developers when they use a technical product in their workflows".) (It can also refer to the experience of developers as employees, as you said.). so it means both.

Comment: In such cases, the developer experience is not much relevant. As developer, I find hexadecimal numbers more convenient. Does that mean scores should be shown in hexadecimal?

Comment: @apaderno hey. That's an invalid analogy. you don't find hexadecimal numbers more convenient. (it's just for some special cases, like working with colors.). in here, the upvote has extra (unnormal) attention, so it gain focus from looking/reading the content/answers. so it's bad for developers.

Comment: You missed the point. As developer, I find hexadecimal number more convenient, but what I find more convenient as developer should not matter for a page that is used also from people who are not developers. The analogy is perfectly valid because what you find more convenient as developer for the voting buttons is irrelevant.

Comment: @apaderno Hey. your previous comment was a "Fallacy". It's defined as "the use of invalid or otherwise faulty reasoning in the construction of an argument which may appear to be a well-reasoned argument if unnoticed". We shouldn't get the point, when there is a fallacy in the reasoning. Btw, I think the main target of stackoverflow is developers, so we should care about their experience/workflow. for developers, even if they don't notice directly, it ruins their focus for focusing on the real content. (I beleive your job/career is not developing.) (for stackexcahnege/mobile, you may be right.)

Comment: This is the meta site for Stack Exchange, not for Stack Overflow. No, Stack Exchange sites are not just for developers; in fact, there are sites about Esperanto, English, Italian, religions, etc. (I do not believe you are a developer, but I do not see how that is relevant, in the same way what you believe about my job is not relevant.)

Comment: @apaderno Man, that wasn't an attack. look at the first post (it's announced for stack overflow). for stackoverflow, this is bad (because stackoverflow users are mainly developers). for the rest of stackexchange, it may be ok. (I'm also aware of other languages.). my main role (job/career) is currently developer, but i think your main career is not a developer (but that's not an attack. I didn't mean "you're not a developer", i meant "your main career is not being a developer"). for the people who are mainly developer (more specifically: the people who use stackoverflow for code), this is bad.

Comment: It is always an attack when you say something about the person who is commenting, instead of commenting on the comment that person wrote, especially when it is something you believe and it is not relevant for what being said.

Comment: @apaderno well, kind of agree. there is a "personal attack". that thing ("i believe your main role is not a developer") was personal. (it wan't an attack. but using something personal like that, i agree that wasn't kind of good.)

Comment: Wow - juxtaposing those two examples really showed my how my eyes kept pulling to the circles!  I mean, after all, things that are circled are meant to draw extra attention, aren't they?

Comment: @Randall Man, it's just talking, it's not a fight. (I see "i feel someone tries to make me cheap" in your comment, but it doesn't exists. (you said that i'm looking for attention, it's not there at all. but why you may think like that? maybe because you think it's a public debate / fight, and i'm trying to make you cheap in that. but it's not, it's just a conversation.). the intension you may see in me, it's not there. I don't have any bad intension. it's just talking.)

Comment: @yaya - Sorry you took that the wrong way!  I meant exactly the opposite.  In general circles are meant to draw attention, like circling the date on receipts for reimbursement.  So, I was agreeing with you that the circled arrows pulled my eyes (my attention) over to the side, instead of the actual answer.  I guess I needed to be more clear I was speaking in the context of the two example pics in your answer, and had seen, but was ignoring, the previous comments directly above.  Regarding those comments, UX vs DX is really splitting hairs to me; aren't Devs a subset of Users in Q&A interface?

Comment: @Randall Thank you. well that refers to "why dx is different than ux"? first reason : for a normal user, the "ui" is usually his "using website" experience. but for a developer, it's direct part of his workflow/life. (an example: "changing the design of a program that bank staffs work with. that will change their work/life". they look at if from the workflow, not from normal ui/ux perspertive.). i'll put another reason on next comment.

Comment: @Randall Second reason: a developer uses Intuition (unconscious reasoning) more than others. a developer will come to stackoverflow, he's focued on his project, and the ui focus will direct to the content, and he/she will use the content. but if the site put extra attention to the like/dislike buttons, this will change the "unconscious focus" of the developer also. for a normal user, that "changing focus" may not really important, but for a developer, that "changing focus" will ruin his "intuition" part also. it makes developer more "unfocused/lazy" in long term, and it'll hurt his/her career.

Comment: @Randall so i think the ui/ux of the products that main target are developers, should be coordinated with developers. they should ask what developers think about it. (you can see the downvotes on the first post. it means they don't like it, it ruins their workflow/intuition part.). But i'm not sure about other stackexcahnge websites. i feel like it's a generally bad move, cause the q/a website content needs focus also. but i think it doesn't hurt them as much as developers.

Answer (score 9):

This is like:

- How can we improve our income?
- Let's make the "Buy" button bigger.

I'm really not interested in this change, either as a member answering questions or an elected moderator. But still, how will the button-pressing rate help the community grow or help answer quality improve?

Potentially some new members will gain a few more votes. Potentially some more members will become active members, right? ...Wait a minute! I see that the downvote button size was increased too.

Regarding the UX, I think that the visual **weight of the post votes counter was significantly decreased** in contrast with the button size. "Accept answer" button was also affected. There was not an improvement but a tradeoff. A change that changes nothing.

Regarding UI, I like [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389650/756067).

Finally, what about "Accept answer" button? It doesn't look like a button at all.

Answer (score 8):

### An analysis of the statistics

When I read lots of numbers, I like to see in which context they are used. Here's my review of those numbers, regardless of the button design<sup>(hint : I moderately dislike them :p)</sup>.

---

> We shared positive results from the experiment: **a net 28% increase in overall votes.**

28% increase compared to what? If it's overall, note that if there are 28% more users overall, there will be a normal and expected 28% increase in votes, too. **No real cause-to-effect can be determined from this number alone.**

---

> - In the previous post, we saw feedback from users with >1k rep who flagged the risk of accidentally voting when checking the post score. We took a closer look at this report and pulled the following data:
> - Last month (Apr 2023), we saw 175k users who voted 870k times. Of those users, only 8% (14k users) had undone their votes.
> - The number of posts that had votes undone only accounted for 3% of total votes. This is the benchmark we will use moving forward.

Five things here :

- **Have you excluded from your search unexperienced users as you looked at >1K users?** Because if so the 8% value is certainly lower than real. We don't have any source to check what you tested, exactly.
- **"only" 8% of potential misvote is an awful lot.** Let's be our kindest and remove half of misvotes from users who actually changed their mind (e.g after a post's edit), we're still left with a very big 4%. **This means that every 25 voters, one has mis-clicked at least once** (one out of ~12 for 8%). Since voting is a critical component and your "lowest barrier to participation", do you actually think this is a good stat?
- Where's the number of votes that got undone? Votes are not users. Some people could be undoing their votes repeatedly, and that'd be interesting to know why!
- "The number of posts that had votes undone only accounted for 3% of total votes.". **Are you actually comparing posts to votes?** Is it from the same time period as the 8%? Total votes over this period, or overall? In what is it relevant to misclicking? **It is extremely unclear what you're talking about here.**
- **Why didn't you checked how many people removed their votes within the 5 or 10 minutes of voting?** Those are very likely actual misvotes : The post likely didn't change meanwhile, and most people quickly realize when they've done something wrong.

---

> Year over year, **we are seeing 28% fewer votes (upvotes + downvotes) and 21% fewer users voting.**

**Again, isn't this due to other reasons? It's really easy to mistake correlations and cause-to-effects relationships.** Users becoming less active overall is a much more reasonable explanation for this : A system that didn't change isn't very likely to change much the behavior of users because in there only the user could have changed!

---

> During our research, we also found that voting is a pain point for new users as well. In April alone, we saw:
>
> - 72k unique users who attempted to vote 166k times (avg 2.3 votes per user).
> - Of those 72k users, 17k users were new users which is 24%
> - This means that 1 in 4 new users attempted to vote, but could not due to system limitations.

Well, let's exclude the absence of source explaining the test procedures because I'm really starting to feel I'm punching a underfed dog to death. First and foremost, what do you mean by "attempted to vote"? How did you notice attempts that failed? If the user failed, then it's not reflected in the "succesfully voted" [KPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_indicator), right? If so, how do you know?

Then, 24% of new users who failed has no meaning if you don't tell how many new users are there in comparison to old users *overall*. For instance, I can have 60% of new users overall, which means that there are less new users who make the mistake than old ones (60% > 24%). If there are only 12% of new users, yes here potentially we have an issue, but a new user's ability to vote still needs to be reviewed with actuals user-experience tests, not KPI reviewing.

### Conclusion

From this text alone and without even considering the design<sup>I moderately dislike :p</sup>, I feel like the KPIs used are at least not explanatory enough. At worst, and that's what I think because they're piling up quite a bit, they're not displaying an honest behavior. Throwing in numbers semi-randomly does not make a point stronger, they need to make sense and be explained correctly.

Here -and complementary to the other answers proving the buttons are not as accessible as you try to make think they are-, I find the downvotes count on this post and the test one much more speaking than any of the numbers you gave. A ratio of 14.8% of "likes" vs total votes on this question means this isn't what the community's core sought at all, ie. the one that run the inn and bring new travellers in. There is no doubt in that.

Answer (score 8):

*My eye-sight is rather poor*.

I have found that, **on non-meta sites**, I seem to have to squint and peer more closely at these new arrows to see if I have voted or not, because the ring highlighting just isn't sufficient.

The previous arrows never made me need to squint.

I also find that after a while, I am getting **eye-strain** and **headaches** from the squinting to check for any previous upvotes/downvotes.

Note that if I don't bother looking at the arrows, then I find no need to squint to be able to read the text - so it isn't that my eyes are completely shot. It is clearly just these arrows and the fact that it is harder to see their highlighting.

So, one has to ask, was any ***accessibility*** checking done when testing these new wonderful (hard to see) buttons..?!

---

It should be noted that, however, **on the meta sites**, the filled-in/inverted highlighting of the vote buttons is perfectly visible. Taking these examples from SuperUser:

Non-meta vs Meta:

[image: Non-meta voting buttons] [image: Meta voting buttons]

Comment: "was any accessibility checking done" - sure, among the developers only of course, who all appear to have a good eye sight. *sad laugh*

Answer (score 5):

I don't like the new styling for two reasons:

1. It doesn't fit in well with the rest of the layout where everything is, well, **rectangular** (search boxes, page buttons, horizontal and vertical lines, profile icons, sidebar panels, selected or marked menu items etc.)
2. For some reason it feels like something is wrong with the voting arrows. Cognitively, the first thing that comes to mind is that some CSS is missing and the browser tries to apply some sort of default rendering.

Honestly, in comparison, the comments' borderless up-arrow and flag look much better.

Answer (score 4):

Fully aware that this seems to be a small minority opinion here, I personally like the change, even though there is always room for improvement.

- Most people seem to agree that the buttons are generally more eye-catching than before(even though for some people that is because they find them ugly **^.^** ). This was the whole point, so at least in that regard, success! (I am avoiding the important accessibility aspect here, about which I don't feel knowledgeable enough to really talk).
- I personally noticed that I'm more likely to leave a vote, especially for the usual *google search -> solution* sort of visits.
- I can understand the opinion that the current buttons feel somewhat out of place with the rest of the style, maybe a square with rounded corners would be more in line with the site's other *button-like things*:

> [image]
> [image]
>
> [image]
> [image]
>
> [image]
> [image]

- On the other hand, that stark difference is part of what makes them stand out so much in the first place.
- While the discussion seems to have remained *mostly* civil, I just want to thank the many members of team **trying** to improve the site for all of us, even though the community often gives them tough love in return :).

Answer (score 3):

I would like that the experiment included a measure on comments, specifically if there is more comments and if comments including content like '+/-1'. That would make also something that doesn't affect the likeness of the votes themselves (after all they scream "USE ME"), but also what actions those users stopped doing.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the new vote button arrows because they have a much more obvious contrast between voted and non-voted arrow vote buttons in dark mode (through the [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/) browser extension), even on meta sites. I use Dark Reader to enable dark mode on all websites whenever possible.

In the previous UI, some SE site themes conflicted with Dark Reader. This made it difficult to see the difference between voted and non-voted posts. The new UI addresses this issue by increasing the area of the button that is a different color if it has been voted on, making it much easier to see the difference between voted and non-voted buttons.

Screenshot of the new vote button UI in Dark Reader dark mode (in Movies & TV SE) — notice that the area covered in orange, contrasting it to the non-voted button, is much larger in the new UI than in the old UI.

[image: screenshot of new vote button UI in Dark Reader dark mode (in Movies & TV SE)]

In the old UI, it was harder to see the contrast since only the arrow had a different color (a smaller area), and some site themes made the difference even less obvious in dark mode.

I hope that SE will eventually implement [native dark mode for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399/162827). This would improve the overall user experience for users who prefer dark mode.

Comment: But that is part of the problem: the experience with the voting buttons changes severely based on which browser extensions were used, which site in the SE network is being visited, or which theme was picked on the site itself.

Comment: @E_net4 I believe that what you've mentioned also applies to the old vote button styling. IMHO, the vote button experience is worse in the old vote button styling, especially in certain site themes. The area covered by the contrasting color of the voted arrow button was too small. The contrast is much easier to see in the new button styling, regardless of the site theme, due to the larger area covered by the contrasting color. I can't comment much on non-dark mode since I never browse sites in non-dark mode.

Comment: The buttons may cover a larger area, but most of that is using a dimmer color, or using stronger, contrasting colors in the outlines. These perceptions may indeed be biased by the use of browser extensions.

Comment: This varies between the SE sites. On many sites the color of the clicked button changes very little and it's actually more difficult to see if you already voted, in comparison to the old icons.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously, this insignificant change should not elicit so much whining.

If you go all ballistic because of a button design change (!) nobody will listen to you when it concerns more serious issues, because you oppose everything anyway.

I know I make the prediction after the fact, which is cheap, but still.

Comment: For me it's about SE lying in our faces, throwing false details (e.g. it was done to improve accessibility while it only harms it) and worse, **ignoring any and all feedback**. I don't care if they'll change the arrows to poo emoji, just do it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to emphasise voting buttons WHY didn't you make them look like buttons?

E.g./ or ⬆️/⬇️

I have never seen a computer application that uses round buttons

Comment: IMHO buttons is buttons even if they are round.

Comment: @PeterKolosov and they are buttons even if they are triangles. Frankly I don't care what shape or understand why this totally unnecessary change generated so much controversy.

Comment: No thanks. It's even worse that that we have now. (Yeah, hard to find something worse, but you did. ;-))

Comment: _"I don't [..] understand why this totally unnecessary change generated so much controversy."_ This is a prime example of [bikeshedding](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/Parkinsons-law-of-triviality-bikeshedding).

Comment: You've never been in the [button's Heaven](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOEl_VVsvDY), right ^^? There are actually a lot of examples of round buttons (excluding "roundish" ones), here are some examples from websites and elsewhere : https://imgur.com/a/2Ef6HrP . You just don't notice them in day-to-day life.

Comment: Primarily, the prevalence of round buttons can be attributed to historical factors rather than considerations of usability. Square buttons, on the other hand, were favored due to their simplicity in terms of implementation. The straightforward shape facilitated easier drawing, click and hover detection, resulting in higher efficiency. Moreover, square shapes and straight lines held dominance in design due to their inherent simplicity, hence round buttons would have been difficult to integrate without compromising layouts stylistically.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like (at least some) people express such a disaffection because of a something called the "mere exposure effect".

> This is a psychological bias that suggests people tend to develop a
> preference for things simply because they are familiar with them.

It is evident that some individuals concoct seemingly rationalized justifications to disapprove of these familiar elements, thereby framing their preferences as matters of personal choice rather than engaging in constructive thinking. Hence, it becomes imperative to approach such discussions with a critical and open-minded attitude.

When I think of a button, I think of something round.
Historical design conventions have predominantly favored round buttons, and this dates back to at least 1880.
On the other side of the spectrum, they could also be squares, but this is often regarded as antiquated (and often for a [good reason](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/AT%26T_push_button_telephone_western_electric_model_2500_dmg_black.jpg)). Personally, I strongly prioritize simplicity and user-friendliness over subjective aesthetics. Round buttons, in particular, convey a sense of a larger click surface area, a crucial aspect contributing to enhanced usability.

Nevertheless, I harbor reservations regarding the compatibility of these circular buttons with the overall design scheme at hand.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. While I'm sure "mere exposure effect" plays a role, the top comments actually point out very valid issues with accessibility. They also highlight weaknesses with the company's analysis and "proof" that these buttons are better. (Honestly I don't think anyone really cares all that much, I'm already used to the new ones, but I do hope they deal with the accessibility concerns)

Comment: I wasn't specifically referencing the top comments. A number of people seemingly criticize mostly how they look, not to mention that once the accessibility issues are taken care of, those buttons are actually easier to use as stated above.

Comment: When I look at my keyboard I don't see many round buttons. In the lab, most of the instruments have a round button for power on/off, but nothing else.

Comment: It wouldn't matter what shape the buttons were if all buttons on SE shared the same characteristics. If a circle is such a great indicator of a button, why are most of the other buttons on the site rectangular? The voting buttons aren't even styled similarly to the "Add comment" button I'm looking at right now which has a slight 3d effect to look clickable.

Comment: @JonCuster Right, but they are not even called buttons. They are called keys. And if all this is irrelevant - the reasons for the keyboard keys being square-shaped is again only historic anyway (but also I suspect easier to press?). (Also there are plenty of modern keyboards with round keys, which I haven't tried, nor I want to). Also the actual buttons in your mouse, which are called push buttons are guess what.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree, exactly.

Answer (score -1):

For devices like Apple Vision Pro, round icons are better. If the icons have sharp corners (like before), it makes **eye tracking** more difficult - people will instinctively stare at the corners.

Apple advises developers to use round-cornered icons when developing apps for visionOS, for the same reason.

(That's **probably not** why they changed the icon.  **I'm just sharing information** that I think might be useful.)

Comment: Off topic: the website in your profile is dead, better change link or remove it.

Comment: I highly doubt the change was made specifically for VR or AR headsets. I'd expect the amount of traffic SE gets from such devices to be negligible. Note as well that [the A/B testing for this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded) was conducted almost a year ago, whereas visionOS was announced last week.

Comment: @F1Krazy: Thank you for your information. But I would like to say that I am only discussing the possible benefits of this change, not the purpose.

Answer (score -28):

If StackExchange wants to increase voting, I encourage StackExchange to actively encourage kindness across its network (and the world) and explain why upvoting is a kind thing to do (and how unnecessary downvoting is a mean thing to do).

I've noticed that quite a few prominent StackExchange users have a 2:1 (or even worse) downvote to upvote ratio. These people often become community moderators, and continue their pattern of negativity.

Perhaps StackExchange should start penalizing users with downvote to upvote ratios that are greater than 1:1.

If you desire healthy and engaged communities, the first step is to act kindly towards other community members.  Slightly changing a button's appearance isn't the big issue.

Upvotes literally cost nothing, yet so many people are incredibly unwilling to be kind enough to upvote helpful posts.  I find it sad and indicative of a larger problem in society.

Comment: What if the great majority of the downvotes *are* necessary? What if the votes are on the post, and have nothing to do with the person who made the post?

Comment: Votes are not for showing kindness, never have been. They are there for quality control. Suggesting voting should be used for kindness is a bad idea. You're right about the larger problem in society though, where everyone seems to think everyone needs to be kind to them instead of controlling the quality of a society.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Then I'm sure the community member could also find an equal number of useful posts to upvote.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell And I think we found the problem.  You do understand that type of thinking is the basis for eugenics?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket If you can make a business case for having a separate "add kindness" button, you can post it as a feature request.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Not just eugenics, any kind of excess on both the left and right of politics will be caused by this problem in society. As long as people can keep extending the overton window under the guise of 'you need to be kind to me and my ideas', you can end up anywhere, including eugenics. That's why a society needs quality control (which involves being mean and 'punching nazis' sometimes) just as much an SE site does.

Comment: The argument of RockPaper is interesting. The point is not that upvoting should be the determined by kindness, of course it must depend on the quality of the question/answer, but the atmosphere of a site also determines the quality of  participation. If you feel that the site is unfriendly, you don't feel involved, you don't like to collaborate, you could be unwilling to make the effort of thinking about a post and evaluate it. You can just think: "I'm not interested in collaborating to such site", you are demotivated.  The vibe  affects the behavior, it is a law of human psychology.

Comment: @BakerStreet Clearly much of the StackExchange community (including some moderators) have demonstrated animosity towards even the idea of kindness.  This speaks volumes about the community and where its headed.  It's sad, but if people don't want to act kindly, at least they won't be alone.

Comment: @BakerStreet I agree that the atmosphere of a site can have a significant impact on the quality of participation, and that a negative atmosphere can lead to demotivation and discouragement. The snarky comments to this answer actually prove the point of the answer and your comment.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket If that's (including some mods being against kindness) what you took away from my comments, read them again. I'm not against kindness, that's why you got my downvote *and a comment explaining why*. I could've been 'mean' and not leave a comment, like so many users complain downvoters do. What I'm against is any suggestion of using votes *for any other purpose than quality control, including 'kindness'*.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell What RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket is saying, I believe, is that _quality control_ (which is indeed necessary) is more enthusiastically practiced when it comes to negativity.

Comment: @Velvel That's not what I read when the post states "explain why upvoting is a kind thing to do". SE should never go around explaining the need for upvotes as 'a kind thing to do' and feed even more into the 'votes are for kindness, downvotes are mean' narrative. Luckily, [they don't have to](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/). Voting is important for quality control, getting users to help with quality control is important, users need votes to be able to help with quality control. No need to explain upvotes as 'kind', they're there for quality control.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell You seem to believe RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket wants to undermine quality control. But I don't think that's the case. (_"Upvotes literally cost nothing, yet so many people are incredibly unwilling to be kind enough to upvote **helpful** posts."_) They're simply stating that *helpful* posts tend to attract less voting that *flawed* ones. But maybe I'm interpreting my own thoughts...

Comment: @Velvel that quote is again equating upvotes to kindness: "unwilling to be kind enough to" before even mentioning quality control (helpful). I don't see any data in this post to support the interpretation that 'helpful posts get less voting than flawed ones' either. Just data that may suggest users most involved in quality control are voting more on flawed posts, and thus have higher downvote-to-upvote ratios.

Comment: In my experience modding another site, any post gets indiscriminate votes (off-topic sob stories get upvotes, out of kindness, I guess?) and these users involved in quality control are sorely needed to counteract the damage done by these indiscriminate votes, sadly, that makes them and their vote ratios, according to this post, 'unkind'.

Comment: I walked away from this because a moderator has already drawn incorrect conclusions & does not appear interested is letting anything change their mind (despite Velvel's polite attempt to steer Tinkeringbell in an accurate direction).  Velvel is completely correct. I'm simply pointing out that ***for helpful posts***, upvoting helps the community & is a kind thing to do. Most readers aren't willing to click a free button to upvote helpful content, yet many people are willing to click to downvote (especially some of the most vocal users/mods). It's sad, and not indicative of a healthy community.

Comment: "I've noticed that quite a few prominent StackExchange users have a 2:1 (or even worse) downvote to upvote ratio." - these are the few who are brave enough to provide the **essential service** of **properly acknowledging** that the overwhelming majority of new questions *are bad and do not help advance the site's goals*. At least on Stack Overflow, anyway.

Comment: "yet so many people are incredibly unwilling to be kind enough to upvote helpful posts." Such "kindness" is in many cases actively counterproductive. We do not praise people who scribble in library books simply because someone who later checked the book out happened to find that it provided a useful explanation. Someone who continually holds a door open for others may be allowing entrance to unauthorized persons, or causing the building's AC system to waste power. Etc.

Comment: Downvoting is for quality control.

Comment: `Perhaps StackExchange should start penalizing users with downvote to upvote ratios that are greater than 1:1.` - dude, I don't know if you are aware of that, but it is already implemented. Every time you downvote, your reputation is decreased, what is this if not a penalty? If someone has enough reputation to use it for downvotes, that means he is good because he didn't simply buy it. As long as it introduces quality control, then I don't give a damn about ratios. If someone fancies in downvoting poor quality answers, then please do, thanks to this no one will see them.

Comment: Re "I've noticed that quite a few prominent StackExchange users have a 2:1 (or even worse) downvote to upvote ratio": Do you mean this is how they voted? I did not know that this information was publicly accessible. But if that is what you mean (of all votes they cast, twice as many were down than up): I have an idea why that is so, and that is that it reflects the number of bad posts compared to the number of good posts. To me on SO, the vast majority of posts is neutral (e.g., outside my expertise). Then there is a large number of bad posts, and very few *really good* posts.

Comment: Nowhere in this response did it imply that the phrase 'upvotes out of kindness' equates to 'not neglecting to upvote a helpful answer'. Therefore, I fail to discern any valid basis to accuse the moderator of 'drawing incorrect conclusions.'

Comment: The higher ratio of downvotes to upvotes has little to do with the moderators being unkind, rather than the verifiable fact that a significant portion of the questions posed are, to put it simply, subpar. In such cases, downvoting actually serves as a benevolent action toward the entire community, occasionally causing emotional reactions from the (usually new) OPs as they struggle to grasp the importance of self-moderation (or perhaps they have not familiarized themselves with the ToS).