# What are the selected vote button colors?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface, javascript

**Edit**: [user3840170's stylesheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389564/how-do-i-change-vote-arrow-buttons-back?noredirect=1&lq=1) does what I was planning to do, and is a cleaner solution than anything I would have come up with.

I'm working on a userscript to reverse the [upcoming vote button changes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows?cb=1)

The color of unselected vote button colors seems to be `rgb(186, 191, 196)` on all SE sites, but the color of selected buttons seems to vary by site. It is the CSS value `--theme-primary-color`, but I'm not 100% sure that isn't going away with the change, so I want to save the colors from as many sites as possible.

Here's a bookmarklet that gets the value:

```
javascript:alert(getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--theme-primary-color'))
```

It works on any page of the site.

### Collected so far

- Meta: `hsl(195.91836735, 80.99173554%, 47.45098039%)`
- Aviation: `hsl(205.7591623, 84.14096916%, 44.50980392%)`
- SO: `hsl(27, 90%, 55%)`
- Unix: `hsl(204.24242424, 70.21276596%, 27.64705882%)`
- Ask Ubuntu: `hsl(12.87958115, 76.70682731%, 48.82352941%)`
- Server Fault: `hsl(358, 62%, 47%)`
- Law, PLDI, probably all beta/beta-design sites: `hsl(205, 47%, 42%)`
- Aviation Meta, PLDI Meta, Law Meta, Meta SO, probably all per-site Metas: `hsl(210, 8%, 5%)`

(If it can be confirmed that `--theme-primary-color` isn't going away in the foreseeable future, collecting these will not be necessary.)

Comment: OK, so what is the question here? Also, for help writing userscripts, you have StackApps, not this site.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard the question is asking for people to get the colors for their favorite sites and share them here. Should I delete this and repost on Stack Apps?

Comment: Isn't this information publically available at Stacks?: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks

Comment: There is already a Stack App (by me) that does this -- https://stackapps.com/questions/9443/revert-stack-exchanges-new-up-down-vote-buttons (although it sets the color to the same value regardless of theme).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't want a complete list here, because of code simplicity and because sites may get new / updated themes. Instead, I would indeed just call

```js
getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--theme-primary-color');
```

to get the theme's primary color, which is (as far as I checked) the color of the vote buttons when selected.

I'm not an employee, but I'll bet a truckload of money that a site gets a new theme before that variable disappears. If it does, your script could just fallback to the stock/beta theme color ...

Comment: So `--theme-primary-color` isn't going away?

Comment: It is the vote button color, and my bookmerklet works with almost exactly that code you wrote.

Comment: Actually it doesn't look like even this is necessary; just pasting `<button class="js-vote-up-btn flex--item s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer  fc-theme-primary" data-controller="s-tooltip" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" aria-pressed="true" aria-label="Up vote" data-selected-classes="fc-theme-primary" data-unselected-classes="" aria-describedby="--stacks-s-tooltip-oxqjjofg">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconArrowUpLg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36"><path d="M2 25h32L18 9 2 25Z"></path></svg>
        </button>` into any site shows in that site's color.

Comment: (although a script might be needed if any classes are removed from the CSS)

Comment: @Someone --theme-primary-color is coming from Stacks: https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/theming/  see https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/blob/develop/lib/exports/constants-colors.less and all sites use stacks now.