# It’s hard to tell how I’ve voted on meta sites. Please make selected and unselected vote buttons different colors

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accessibility

[image]

The only indication of how I have voted on a post is the thin black circle around the vote I have selected.

Whereas before, it was much more clear:

[image]

Please make the unselected vote button arrows the light grey, instead of matching the black used for the selected vote button.

Comment: This is also a problem when using the "Bedtime mode" on Android, which enables Grayscale display. The shading is _very_ subtle, and at a quick glance I might ignore the difference thinking it an artefact of lighting or angle of view.

Comment: Hey, at least your Upvote turns blue. We don't even get that on the math.se meta.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Oof, that’s bad. If you zoom way in, a selected vote button on math.se is actually the dark navy of the site’s theme. But totally indistinguishable from the unselected button.

Comment: Wow, changing things that nobody asked for isn't enough, they also have to do it in a sloppy way...

Comment: Funny how this is the case and yet the original claim was that they were doing it "in order to improve accessibility".

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine It really begs the question, “did you even check meta sites before shipping this?”

Comment: The new voting buttons are objectively worse. I don't understand why this was done.

Comment: @paradroid To be frank, I dislike them everywhere, but they’re especially terrible on meta sites.

Comment: Isn't grey meant for disabled buttons? The button is not disabled: you can click it again to undo the vote. (And I think the only reason the circle border goes darker is because it would disappear against the grey.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton See the image of how it was before.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I'm not saying it was great before (although on SO we got orange for the vote we'd used where applicable), but if they're trying to make an improvement, greying out what is now the background of the button is diametrically opposed to that. At least here it went blue.

Comment: There is a user-script/style workaround if you are so inclined https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389564/how-do-i-change-vote-arrow-buttons-back

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. This is not by design - we'll work on a solution in the near future and update the post here once we've addressed it.

Comment: @Catija yeah, destroy the working one ( that was only need more padding on the mobile applications where it is hard to click correctly) and try to solve the new issues. Do you think that circle button solves the issue, then continue to bookmark, activity, Share, Edit, Follow, Flag, etc. they are all waiting

Comment: @Catija The by-design version is also hard to see, as many people have pointed out here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows

Comment: Posted a seemingly universal solution to a broader discussion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389672

Answer (score 20):

Posting the [same answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389771/1324540) I put on the update post about this.

I want to acknowledge everyone who has indicated that with the new buttons it is harder to tell whether you have already voted on something or not. This is an issue that makes it harder to engage on the platform, which we take seriously. We saw that this problem was especially prevalent on the Meta sites because they use grayscale.

We just rolled out a change across Meta sites on the network, making it much more obvious to see that you have voted on a question or answer. Now, after you have voted the whole button should appear dark, rather than just the outer ring, with the arrow inside appearing lighter.

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

If you find a Meta site where the updated style is not live, please let us know so we can address it.

On the network sites (excluding Meta) the coloration of the voting buttons varies based on the theme of the site, so they don’t look the same everywhere. If there are specific sites where you are finding the same problem of visibility after voting, please let us know in the comments here.

Comment: It looks really nice! Here on this site, it looks much closer to how the buttons used to appear before the 2018 design changes

Comment: Thanks. I believe math.stackexchange needs this change also.

Comment: Yup, looks much better. Commenting, as requested, to echo that math.se has a similar problem on the main site. I don't know if this fix or some other approach is appropriate, but I think it needs something.

Comment: I will add a link to the relevant post on [math.meta.se]: [It’s become difficult to see visually if I’ve upvoted a post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35751). (This site was mentioned in the previous comments.)

Comment: This is so bad on the mathematics main site. I don't understand why this hasn't been fixed yet

Comment: [Still not fixed for main sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389668/i-cant-see-if-ive-already-voted-on-something)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda its on our radar. I'm sorry that it is taking so long, but we do plan to address it in the first half of 2024, which I also noted [on that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389668/i-cant-see-if-ive-already-voted-on-something#comment1323206_389668).