# I can't see if I've already voted on something

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, voting, accessibility

On many sites, I can't see the slight color change that indicates I've already voted unless I look *very* carefully. This seems like a massive accessibility issue, given that my vision is above average and I'm still struggling to use the UI.

[image: A question with an upvote; the vote button is slightly blue colored]

The color change between the up and down arrows is almost indistinguishable to me, especially at the now very small size of the arrows on my monitor. The background seems to be slightly darker, and the border is darker, but these are details that are much much more subtle of changes than the old UI.

The specific colors chosen seem like the main issue. The background is just *3.5% darker* when the button has been clicked, the saturation of the color used for the arrow is less than 50%, and the lightness of 41% is rather similar to the 25% of the unclicked arrow. While if I zoom in several times the difference is clearer, I don't always have the luxury of seeing my screen right up close.

This could be easily remedied by using a brighter, more saturated color, and bigger difference in brightness. For example, here's a (very rough) mockup where I've just increased the saturation and lightness of the theme color, and the saturation of the background:

[image: Brighter, more saturated colors]

Upon further inspection it seems the color used for the buttons is the site's theme color; this worked fine when the buttons were huge solidly colored blocks, but seriously needs to be looked at again when the only solidly colored part of the button is smaller than the number below it, especially for sites like those using the default theme where the primary color is so close to dark gray.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It’s hard to tell how I’ve voted on meta sites. Please make selected and unselected vote buttons different colors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389563/it-s-hard-to-tell-how-i-ve-voted-on-meta-sites-please-make-selected-and-unselec)

Comment: @honk That one is about child meta sites. This seems to be about non-meta.

Comment: @BryanKrause: True, but it's the same problem. I guess we have a general problem here ;)

Comment: @honk Indeed, the voting here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows would indicate others also see the general problem.

Comment: I can see it quite clearly...

Comment: The goal is to increase the number of votes. Perhaps this increases the number of votes by forcing you to click it over and over to even tell if you voted?

Comment: @Chris-RegenerateResponse I think I've (unintentionally) retracted more votes than I've cast in the last week...

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms I've done it more than once. It's even harder to tell on some sites than others.

Comment: @Chris-RegenerateResponse Yes! The next step is to allow for multiple votes on the same content, and we're done!

Comment: Moving to leave open as this was tagged as under review by a staff member (not just a mod unlike the other one).

Comment: The operating system vendors has been doing this [for many decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) now. And there is a special place in hell reserved for [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME). (Yes, it can be changed, even in Windows, but in obscure places and/or ways.)

Comment: We have the same issue on our main site: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1169/5406

Comment: We know this issue persists. I don't have much of an update yet, but just wanted to share that we do plan to work on this in the first half of 2024.

Comment: @Sasha while very far guess better than nothing/never, thanks for the update. (Also, related, without official roadmap it's impossible for us to know what the developers are working on.)

Comment: I've updated to status-completed and posted an answer with more details below.

Comment: Switching it back to grey for unvoted and orange for voted would solve this problem far better, but what do I know

Comment: @TylerH Orange doesn't work for all the SE themes, unless I misunderstanding your suggestion

Answer (score 25):

This is what a downvote looks like on the math.se main site:

[image: image of incompetent UX design]

There might be even less contrast than in yours.

We're like the second or third biggest sub-site. Did they not bother to check what it looks like, or did they look at that and think "That's great! Much better than what we have now."?

Answer (score 19):

As far as I recall, the new voting buttons resemble those of around-2015-era. Nothing good or bad in that fact in particular, however by looking into the old icons we may come to a trade-off / solution to the readability problem...

And here it is: if Stack Exchange *decides to keep* these icons*, it's at least possible to make them more contrasty in a way it was done several years ago (pic 1 with blue button) - and in a similar way tweak the arrows for metas (pic 2, may add more contrast) and dark theme with color accents (pic 3) and dark theme without color accents (pic 4) (is it even a thing btw? meta SO doesn't seem to have a dark theme)

[image]

<sup>* - I mean, I do realize that the current design is far from being widely accepted by community, but here we're talking of solving at least the readability problem</sup>

Comment: Fitting that this was the first post I noticed [the newly updated style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auDbN.png) on!

Answer (score 10):

Looks like this has been fixed, at least on MSE:

> [image]

The color when I hover over it also changes:

> [image]

On other sites, it still looks like these:

> [image] [image][image]
>
> [Hinduism] [English] [Hinduism Meta]

[(Edit: Apparently it's now fixed on all per-site-metas)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows/389771#389771)

Comment: Reverted back in 10... 9... 8...

Comment: Anyway, it's only here on MSE. So just some early test. With total lack of communication with staff, we can't possibly know.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard - yeah, I realized that after checking some other sites. The new version is certainly an improvement in that regard, though.

Answer (score 6):

A fix has been deployed across all sites. The voting buttons now use the same styling that was [previously only used on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389668/i-cant-see-if-ive-already-voted-on-something) network-wide.

I've included an image from the Mathematics site as an example.

[image: up and down arrows with vote counts, the arrow on the left is darker than the arrow on the right]

The top arrow on the left is how it appeared before the change was pushed. The arrow on the right is how it currently appears.

I've updated the tag to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Seems I was the first to [notice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37315/was-the-style-of-the-up-down-vote-arrows-changed) this. :)

Comment: I don't think this is a "fix". The voting buttons on Stackoverflow are too prominent. All I see in the page is that bold, brown circle :-/ Please make them stand out less. I have posted this as proposal [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398317/236085), in case you want to vote on it

Comment: The problem mentioned by @LuisMendo is also happening in SOpt. The arrow color is now brown-ish, are you sure it should be this way? https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRsAf.jpg

Comment: FWIW, in "Force dark mode" in Chrome & related browsers, there's still not much difference between the look of voted and unvoted on MSO and other meta sites using a grey theme.

Answer (score 4):

We are also affected by this issue on our main site: [New voting buttons make it hard to distinguish voted upon posts on MAIN site](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1169/5406)

This is what the voting buttons on Bitcoin.SE look like:

[image: Voting buttons from upvoted post on Bitcoin SE]

Just as Radvylf Programs said in the initial post here, I have great vision and I find myself needing to explicitly check to see whether I have voted on things.

Answer (score 1):

After [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398314/236085), the voting buttons on Stackoverflow are *too prominent*. They stand out too much, and distract from the text, or in fact from anything else on the page. For example, the check mark is hardly visible in comparison (see images below). Please tone down the voting buttons a little.

[image]  [image]

Comment: Same in SOpt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRsAf.jpg