# Vote button remains highlighted after retracting the vote

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, voting, highlighting

The recently changed vote buttons remain highlighted after retracting the vote:

> [image]

When you retract your vote the button remains highlighted (with lighter colors), highlighting disappears after tapping somewhere outside the button or refreshing the page. Until button is highlighted it's hard to understand did your vote retracted or not.

Similar behavior is observable on other sites, but with site specific colors.

Easily reproducible on own posts due to immediately auto retracting.

Comment: This is the "on hover" coloring and it's the reason I kept toggling my upvote on some spam post somewhere.  On main sites (where the button styles are the reverse) it looks more like an upvote than an upvote does.

Comment: It's even worse in dark mode. I posted an [answer on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418857/8967612) about this last year.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390515/upvote-downvote-indicator-lost-after-edit

Comment: Has this been fixed already? I am unable to recreate it now. I wonder if this got fixed as part of something else that I've missed

Comment: @Connell https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389668/i-cant-see-if-ive-already-voted-on-something just got tagged as completed.