# Upvote / downvote indicator lost after edit

Tags: bug, status-review, design, voting, highlighting

When I edit a post, and return to the updated page when saving the edit, the upvote indicator to show that I had previously upvoted the post is lost.

This seems to be related to the recent and unfortunate [button redesign.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows)

I speculate that returning to the page after editing reloads and rerenders only some of the page's elements, and that there is a bug in this logic (but I could merely be demonstrating my lack of understanding of web design here).

Also, tangentially, I believe I have occasionally managed to turn the button into "highlighted" when I tried to vote. This *should* be a transient state which disappears when the cursor is not over the button (and ideally, of course, it should be visually distinct enough that it cannot be confused with an upvoted state) but it happened to me on a mobile device a few minutes ago. This seems similar and possibly related to [Vote button remains highlighted after retracting the vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390101/vote-button-remains-highlighted-after-retracting-the-vote)

I am using Firefox on iOS 16.5, iPhone 12 Mini.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: @Greenonline the screenshot would probably just show a freshly edited question without upvotes, which isn't really helpful. In this case here I think the textual description is enough to find out what's wrong.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the redesign was entirely contained in the style sheet…  (given [my user style undoing it](/a/389568/620615))

Comment: Often, all the tags are also missing (refreshing the page brings them back).

Comment: I’ve had the highlighting problem (where tapping a button only highlights it and doesn’t perform the action) intermittently on many buttons. I assumed it was a Safari bug (I’m also on iOS 16.5).