# Problem with vote buttons—color change without actually voting

Tags: discussion, bug, design, user-interface

I've encountered an issue with vote buttons.  I think it's a real issue when using a tablet (for reasons that will become apparent), but I've reproduced it in a PC browser.

The new vote buttons can change color to something very similar to an actual vote when the button is the active selected element on the screen, but no vote has been made.

For example: This shows a real vote

[image]

This shows what the screen looks like when I mouse-over, click a vote button, move the mouse, and then release the click:

[image]

So, one might ask "why would anyone do that with a mouse?", and that's certainly a valid question.

This isn't a problem on a computer browser.  It's a problem when browsing on a tablet.  About a half dozen times, I'm interacting with the site, notice a red circle, and think "I didn't upvote this" (because, of course, I never downvote ;-) ), only to find that the button was the active screen element because I touched it with my finger while scrolling.

In any case, these two button states seem too close in appearance to me.

Lastly, as I've been browsing SE on a tablet for a decade or so, and never noticed it before the redesigned buttons, I assume it has to do with the updated buttons.

Note:  I'm not a developer, web or otherwise—if I got any of the words wrong, I'd appreciate correction.

Comment: I suggest that the obvious "You should use the Android App" answers don't address this issue.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390101/478746

Comment: I can offer a situation where this could happen using a mouse, though it's probably not very common: You see an answer you think is good and click on the vote button, but on second thought you decide it's not good, so while still holding the mouse button drag the mouse to the side to "cancel" the vote. But the vote button appears to have been clicked.

Comment: ... and merely tabbing to the vote button with the tab key also highlights it.

Comment: This kind of thing has been reported before, but this is probably the first one since [Oct 26 when they said they fixed this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394232/323179).

Comment: @Laurel -- thanks for pointing that out.  Perhaps this is some sort of regression error, and you just narrowed things down for the devs.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I'm unable to reproduce the orange + blue glow effect on my end  (desktop or mobile device) that I see in your screenshot. When I repeat the steps you mentioned, I only see a light blue fill inside the voting buttons when it's "stuck" in the focus state style after clicking and mousing away (vs orange). You mentioned this happens on PC, can you specify the browser your using when you see this and confirm if this is on Stack Overflow or any other SE site?

Comment: @Carog -- I think the orange might be part of the style sheet on EESE (electronics).  This stack seems blue with a blue ring.  I'm using chrome on PC, and chrome for android.  Checked in Bing on PC, and it's the same.

Comment: But really, it is just mouse click and hold on the button, move the mouse off the button, and release.