# Vote Button :active state not reset after mouseDrag

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, voting

The Vote button got some styling changes <sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389668/i-cant-see-if-ive-already-voted-on-something/398314#398314)</sup>, which introduced a state where the `::active` color does not reset, whereas the arrow stays white, becoming invisible on the white background.

1. Press (and hold) vote button
2. Drag outside the button
3. Release

---

[image]

Comment: That's a neat trick! Disappearing arrows! There's a similar bug on mobile where the button stays highlighted in blue when you press & drag to avoid registering a click

Comment: Was this an issue before yesterday?

Comment: Another side effect of this is if you change to another tab then back, the tooltip appears. This "issue" occurs for pretty much any element that can receive focus (not anchors) and is styled differently when focused. Including this comment box, the result on the voting buttons is just inconvenient due to the specific style being used for focused vote buttons.

Comment: @Piper I'm sure people tried, so fact no bug report until now means that no, it's a rather new bug. Thanks for looking into it! :)

Answer (score 3):

We deployed a fix for the issue. This is a compromise given the way our buttons show focus on `:focus-visible` while conditional focus classes apply to `:focus` .

The arrow should no longer be invisible anymore when you press and hold + drag outside the button.