# What do the "new" circles around the up-vote and down-vote arrows mean?

Tags: support

The circles appear on both up and down votes.  What do they mean? And darkened arrows also appear on both. (?)

I cannot tell now if I've already voted on a question or answer; both arrows are darkened, instead of just one. I just found out that the arrows change colors. But not knowing this, with both darkened, it was confusing.

Comment: Landing pads for your fingers.

Comment: @Trilarion landing path for total votes, bookmark, activity, share, edit, follow, flag, upvote for comment, flag for comment?...

Answer (score 3):

They attract the eye to the buttons and according to Stack Exchange's testing that results in [28% more voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows)

Voting on that question does show that they are not universally popular though.

Comment: @RobertLongsonI don't mind the circles to entice more voting.  But the "darkened arrows" were such a big hep in letting me know which I've already  up or down voted....Oh, I just saw that they turn blue!

Comment: The whole circle changes colour when you've voted.

Comment: Yes, except that on most sites, the color change is so minor that you can't see it. Apparently, that's a known bug. So known that it was known back in October when this idea was first trialed. But not well enough known that it's been addressed yet. Supposedly, it is planned.