# "Null" error message when viewing the total vote count, if user ceases to have the privilege to see vote counts after the page is loaded

Tags: bug, reputation, error-message, vote-count

When I downvoted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389556/1345677), I got 99 reputation on MSE. As you know, by reaching 100 rep you can see the vote count totals. I downvoted the answer, and I got 99 reputation.

I didn't reload the page after (I know, it will help, but I want to report this bug). Then I tried to see the vote counts on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389543/1345677), and the page shows this notification error...

> [image: bug]

It shows "null". Can you please fix this so it shows an appropriate error message instead of "null"?

Comment: I can reproduce this error, luckily I'm right on the edge :)

Comment: Will `FILE_NOT_FOUND` be ok?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`

Comment: Ideally, the score will become unclickable when reputation drops below the privilege requirement. There is already code that "live update" things on the page, e.g. time stamps, your own reputation when it changes, etc, so it can in theory perform this extra check.